# DataGridView, привязка данных

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть некий эл-т DataGridView в котором в ручном режиме созданы колонки, делается это примерно так:

```
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Колонка 1", "Заголовок 1"); 
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Колонка 2", "Заголовок 2"); 
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Колонка 3", "Заголовок 3");
```

Как сделать так, что бы когда источник данных указан через свойство **DataSource**

```
dataGridView.DataSource = mySource;
```

Значения из *нужных свойств* моего источника, попадали в *нужные колонки* в **DataGridView**. Например, предположим, что мой источник данных содержит свойства **A**, **B**, **C** и допустим я хочу чтобы:

- свойство **A** выводилось в колонке с именем "**Колонка 3**"
- свойство **В** в колонке с именем "**Колонка 2**"
- а свойство **C** в колонке с именем  "**Колонка 1**"

P.S. Сейчас чтобы добиться желаемого результата приходится проходить по источнику данных в цикле и добавлять из него данных в **DataGridView** следующим образом:

```
dataGridView.Rows.Add("Значение для ячейки 1", "Значение для ячейки 2", "Значение для ячейки 3");
```

Comment: DataMember?

Comment: Это несколько не то, т.к. DataMember задает имя списка или таблицы в источнике данных, для которого DataGridView отображает данные. 

Я же хочу сделать следующее:

1) Поместить мои пользовательские типы, например в List<T>
2) Привязать этот список через DataSource, но при этом чтобы  свойства моих пользовательских типов, находящихся в коллекции, отражались на нужные мне колонки в DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно свойство [DataPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx). Приведу небольшой пример. Пусть есть класс, описывающий наши данные:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass(string a, string b, string c)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
        }

        public string A { get; set; }

        public string B { get; set; }

        public string C { get; set; }
    }
```

В DataGridView добавим колонки:

```
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                         {
                                             DataPropertyName = "A",
                                             HeaderText = "Заголовок 1"
                                         });
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                         {
                                             DataPropertyName = "B",
                                             HeaderText = "Заголовок 2"
                                         });
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                         {
                                             DataPropertyName = "C",
                                             HeaderText = "Заголовок 3"
                                         });
```

Создадим коллекцию и укажем ее как источник данных:

```
            var data = new List<MyClass>
                           {
                               new MyClass("1", "2", "3"),
                               new MyClass("4", "5", "6"),
                               new MyClass("7", "8", "9")
                           };
            dataGridView.DataSource = data;
```

Вот и все.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно! )