# Привязка данных в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Возникла такая проблема.
У меня есть моя структура:

```
public struct GRIDVIEW
    {
        public List<string> kod;
        public List<string> time;
        public List<string> pers;
    }
```

Есть dataGridView с тремя колонками, которые я создал в конструкторе на элементе dataGridView, условно: А, В, С.
Каким образом я могу привязать свою структуру как источник данных для датавьювера?

Просто `dataGridView.DataSource = grid;` не работает.
После привязывания пустота. Даже ошибок не выдает.

Comment: В ответах ниже не акцентировали внимание на одном важном моменте. Данные должны быть сделаны свойствами, а не полями: "public struct GRIDVIEW
    {
        public List<string> kod { get; set; }
        public List<string> time { get; set; }
        public List<string> pers { get; set; }
    }". Поэтому и не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Покажу вам настоящую привязку данных. Суть настоящей привязки в том, что вы вообще забываете о существовании `DataGridView` и работаете с данными.

Простой пример использования `INotifyPropertyChanged` и привязки данных `DataBindings` в Windows Forms. Обратите внимание, я нигде не использую `DataSource` и не обращаюсь к ячейкам, но оно работает.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BindingList<Person> _persons; // в коде не обращайтесь к полю _persons, вместо этого обращайтесь к свойству Persons

    public BindingList<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // вот она, привязка данных
        // DataSource - название свойства контрола, которое надо привязать
        // this - класс, в котором находится свойство с данными
        // nameof(Persons) - то же самое что строка "Persons", срока с названием самого свойства с данными
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(Persons));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persons = new BindingList<Person>();

        Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Иван", SurName = "Петров" });
        Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Алексей", SurName = "Сидоров" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Класс с данными выглядит пострашнее, чем вы показали в вопросе, но по сути одна и та же методика повторяется везде.

```cs
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _surName;

    // если включена автогенерация колонок, заголовки колонок берутся отсюда
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    public string SurName
    {
        get => _surName;
        set
        {
            _surName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Теперь можно с данными вытворять любые фокусы в совершенно любом месте кода и в любое время, например

```cs
Persons = new BindingList<Person>();
Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "Иван", SurName = "Петров" });
Persons[0].Name = "Вася";
```

А отображаемые данные будут меняться в табличке автоматически. И такую штуку можно провернуть с многими свойствами, например с `Label.Text` или `Button.Top`. Вы меняете данные, а контрол сам следит за их обновлением и обновляется, совершенно добровольно.

Кстати, соберетесь освоить WPF, UWP или Xamarin: там привязка данных - единственный способ выжить и писать вменяемые приложения, и работает точно так же как я выше показал. Так что не проходите мимо, это полезно и обязательно пригодится.

Еще один бонус привязки данных в том, что вы можете к одному свойству с данными привязать сколько угодно свойств контролов. Быть может встречали ситуацию, когда надо одно и то же записать в несколько контролов. Так вот, с привязкой данных, вы просто вяжете нужные контролы к одному свойству, а затем в коде при изменении данных в этом свойстве все привязанные контролы одновременно отреагируют на это изменение. Меньше кода - больше пользы.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Реализовал данный метод у себя. Но проблема есть. Сделал все по примеру, что вы указали. Но, как только доходит до `dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(GRID));`, выдает ошибку: **Привязка к свойству или столбцу GRID для DataSource невозможна. Имя параметра dataMember.** Автогенерацию колонок включил.

Comment: @АлексейШнякин а что такое GRID? Покажите код этого свойства.

Comment: Да, извините. Ошибся. Передавал класс, вместо свойства)
Но теперь проблема в том, что в таблице появляется то ли первая, то ли последняя строка. Не пойму. Остальных данных после заполнения нет. Только одна строка. Заполняю результатом sql запроса.

Comment: @АлексейШнякин покажите, как заполняете. Поставьте точку останова на строчку после заполнения, посмотрите, что в отладке содержит свойство. Вероятно, привязка здесь не при чем, и проблема в заполнении. Что будет, если вы добавите строки вручную, как в примере?

Comment: `MainViewGrid = new BindingList<GRID>();
MainViewGrid.Add(new GRID 
{
_kod = reader[0].ToString().Trim(),
_time = reader[1].ToString().Trim(),
_pers = reader[2].ToString().Trim(),
_eo_kod = reader[3].ToString().Trim(),
_eo_name = reader[4].ToString().Trim(),
_eo_displayName = $"({reader[3].ToString().Trim()}) {reader[4].ToString().Trim()}",
_raw_kod = reader[5].ToString().Trim()
});`
Ну, все в цикле  while (reader.Read())

Comment: Да, я понял ошибку. Я в заполнении всегда обнуляю данные `MainViewGrid = new BindingList<GRID>();` вынес за цикл. Спасибо большое вам за помощь! Теперь буду практиковать данный метод.

Comment: @АлексейШнякин `_kod = reader[0].ToString().Trim()` это же поле? Pаботайте с свойством вместо поля, типа `Kod = ...`.

Comment: `private string kod;
[DisplayName("Код")]
public string _kod
{
get => kod;
set
{
kod = value;
OnPropertyChanged();
}
}`

Comment: Я в попыхах чуть по другому назвал все. Не по феншую) Щас исправлю)

Comment: @АлексейШнякин тогда просто у вас с именованиями проблема, потому что я не понял что есть что из-за странных названий свойств. [Соглашения о написании кода на C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [Правила именования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Comment: Ммм. А у меня еще вопрос. Вот, допустим, у меня 3 свойства в классе, которые я заполняю данными. Но в таблице нужно вывести только два из них. Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: @АлексейШнякин добавьте над свойством, которое надо скрыть из таблицы, аттрибут `[Browsable(false)]`. Либо по индексу колонки в самой `DataGridView` задайте ей ширину `0`. Это в случае, если надо программно скрыть/показать.

Comment: Мое почтение!!)

Comment: @АлексейШнякин кстати, доки по ссылкам что я скинул, лучше читайте на английском, перевод там кривоват.

Comment: @АлексейШнякин [бонус](https://habr.com/ru/post/211899/), рекомендую

Comment: Спасибо. Обязательно ознакомлюсь. У меня еще вопрос возник. Я попробовал провернуть использование экого способа для привязки данных к ComboBox'у. У меня 3 свойства, два из которых я скрыл с помощью `[Browsable(false)]`. Я подумал, что так как осталось одно свойство видимое, он его и будет отображать в выпадающем списку комбобокса. Данные добавились, в комбобоксе по колличеству элементов все норм. Но во всех элементах .Text = `MainEdit.DataGridComboBox` MainEdit- имя решения, DataGridComboBox - имя класса.

Comment: То есть, данные наполняются. Но, возможно, я что-то не так делаю касательно привязки к ComboBox.

Comment: @АлексейШнякин перед биндингом добавьте строчку `comboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(DataGridComboBox.<имя вашего свойства>);` Либо в дизайнере впишите туда же имя свойства без "DataGridComboBox.", просто имя. [Там еще есть нюансы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9521980/12888024)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115862/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot----datagridview).

Comment: @АлексейШнякин полечить тормоза можно попробовать [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182133/373567). Помимо этого для отображения какой-то части коллекции, например через фильтрацию, можно воткнуть как прокси-сущность между контролом и данными [`BindingSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8), и через него управлять отображением.

Comment: @aepot Ваше решение применять с MVVM или(и) MVP?
Как ваше решение применять с MVVM или(и) MVP?

Comment: @eusataf Winforms [в последних версиях](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-cross-platform-dotnet-maui-command-binding/) за счет доработки API контролов можно и MVVM применять полноценно, а так MVP. WPF - только MVVM.

Comment: @aepot Вы рекомендовали: [Особенности реализации MVP для Windows Forms |habr.com](https://habr.com/ru/articles/211899/) 
**1.** Это актуально для Framework 4.7-8?
**2.** Может за прошедшие годы вы наши пример проще для Framework 4.7-8?
Или не ныть и прорабатывать этот пример?

Comment: @eusataf Framework 4.x устарел, а так пробуйте, версия особо не имеет значения. Я всего-лишь писал, что в свежей версии проще применять MVVM, а MVP подходит везде.

Comment: @aepot **1.** Как получить строку dataGridView1 выбранную пользователем в данном решении?
`dataGridView1.SelectionChanged`? или можно как-то по моднее и по понтовее? **2.** Можно чтобы строка попадала в свойство формы (или в **VM**)?

Comment: Я не помню, 100 лет на винформах ничего не писал.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше через класс.

Вам нужно свойство DataPropertyName. Пусть есть класс, описывающий ваши данные:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

В DataGridView добавим колонки:

```
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                     {
                                         DataPropertyName = "A",
                                         HeaderText = "Заголовок 1"
                                     });
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                     {
                                         DataPropertyName = "B",
                                         HeaderText = "Заголовок 2"
                                     });
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                                     {
                                         DataPropertyName = "C",
                                         HeaderText = "Заголовок 3"
                                     });
```

Создадим коллекцию и укажем ее как источник данных:

```
        var data = new List<MyClass>
                       {
                           new MyClass("1", "2", "3"),
                           new MyClass("4", "5", "6"),
                           new MyClass("7", "8", "9")
                       };
        dataGridView.DataSource = data;
```

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/311912/datagridview-привязка-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/311912/datagridview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)