# Как постоянно заполнять ListBox без сброса данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Как постоянно заполнять ListBox без сброса данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
customListBox.Items.Add(newItem)
```

Comment: Еще можно привязать его к `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` через `Binding`, и работать с коллекцией, а не с контролом. Вообще прямая работа с контролами в WPF - это плохая практика. ([ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php), [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.2.php), [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/bind-wpf-controls-to-data-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/bind-wpf-controls-to-a-dataset?view=vs-2019))

Comment: @aepot соглашусь с Вами. Просто не работал с WPF ни разу) Не довелось

Comment: Winforms? [Вот такую штуку видели?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567)

Comment: Ещё можно к `ObservableCollection<MyWifesItem>`