# Работа с бд и DataGriedView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Как можно выбрать значение колонки **Расчетный счет** из верхней таблицы, использую записи из нижней таблицы?

```
 private void Contractor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "database1DataSet1.Bank". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.bankTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet1.Bank);
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "database1DataSet.Contractor". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.contractorTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Contractor);          
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [А еще так можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567). Другими словами, вы можете загрузить данные из БД в свою модель данных, привязать ее к таблице, и уже работать с данными забыв про существование DGV. А DGV будет заниматься только тем, что отображать изменения, внесенные в данные, самостоятельно.

Comment: Для фильтрации и сортировки отображаемой коллекции, на случай, если надо управлять отображением не меняя саму коллекцию, есть прокси-класс [`BindingSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8).