# С# Сравнить два списка и по уникальным словам в строках

Tags: c#, linq

Всем привет есть два списка и нужно их сравнить по уникальным словам в строках например в list1 есть строка **"Реготун Д — Гноевой Р"** а в list2 есть строка **"Дмитрий Реготун (Укр) — Роман Гноевой (Укр)"** заметно что они отличаются и нужно сравнить например если с первого списка брать фамилию Реготун или Гноевой и искать совпадения в list и результат писать в вывод что он равны. Написал такой странный код, подход плохой и выводит не всё. Подскажите как осуществить данную задачу.

```
 List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"Реготун Д — Гноевой Р", "Клипперс — Денвер", "Хорнсби Ку Ринг Гай Спайдерс — Сидней Кометс"};
            List<string> list2 = new List<string>{"Дмитрий Реготун (Укр) — Роман Гноевой (Укр)", "Лос-Анджелес Клипперс — Денвер Наггетс с ОТ", "Хорнсби — Сидней Кометс с ОТ", "Реготун Д — Гноевой Р"};
            string result = "";
            foreach(var list1Res in list1)
            {
                    string[] Contains = list1Res.Split('—');
                    Console.WriteLine(Contains[0]);
                    foreach(var list2Res in list2)
                    {
                        if(list2Res.Contains(Contains[0]))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(list1Res + " list1 равен list2");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `например если с первого списка брать фамилию` как понять, где фамилия? Данные не структурированы.

Comment: @aepot > как понять, где фамилия? Данные будут разные как в этих строках, зависимости порядка нету где будет фамилия например в  первом list мы имеем **Реготун Д — Гноевой Р** например можно брать первое слово до — это будет Д, к примеру если оно меньше длины в 3 знака, то берем второе слово после —    это будет Гноевой и поэтому слову можно найти совпадение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стесняйтесь бить код на методы. Выделяйте примитивные подзадачи отдельно. Тогда и код писать будет проще, и читаеть его потом легче.

Данную задачу можно свести к совпадающим словам. Так как где имя, где фамилия - не понятно, то можно просто считать, что пары равны, если слово в левой части содержится в левой части второй пары, и одновременно слово в правой части содержится в правой части второй пары. Тогда добавив фильтрующее условие, что это слово должно быть не менее 4 символов в длину, можно получить желаемый результат.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "Реготун Д — Гноевой Р", "Клипперс — Денвер", "Хорнсби Ку Ринг Гай Спайдерс — Сидней Кометс" };
    List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "Дмитрий Реготун (Укр) — Роман Гноевой (Укр)", "Лос-Анджелес Клипперс — Денвер Наггетс с ОТ", "Хорнсби — Сидней Кометс с ОТ", "Реготун Д — Гноевой Р" };

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list2.Where(x => list1.Any(y => ComparePair(x, y)))));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static bool ComparePair(string left, string right)
{
    string[] tokensLeft = left.Split('—');
    string[] tokensRight = right.Split('—');
    int matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        if (HaveCommonWord(tokensLeft[i], tokensRight[i]))
            matches++;
    return matches == 2;
}

private static bool HaveCommonWord(string left, string right)
{
    const int minLength = 4;
    var wordsLeft = left.Split(' ').Where(w => w.Length >= minLength);
    var wordsRight = right.Split(' ').Where(w => w.Length >= minLength);
    return wordsLeft.Any(word => wordsRight.Any(w => w == word));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Дмитрий Реготун (Укр) - Роман Гноевой (Укр)
Лос-Анджелес Клипперс - Денвер Наггетс с ОТ
Хорнсби - Сидней Кометс с ОТ
Реготун Д - Гноевой Р
```

То есть, все элементы списка 2 содержатся в списке 1.

Comment: буду расшаривать методы и учить linq - полезная штука =) Это магия всё работает отлично, по сравнению с тем что я придумал не сравнить =) Спасибо))