# Удаление строчки из Datagridview, созданной на основе моего класса

Tags: c#, datagridview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить выделенную строчку по нажатию кнопки "удалить" из datagridview, источником к которому является мой класс.
Есть кнопка добавления объектов:

```
            workers.Add(new employee(textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value, textBox2.Text));
        var add = workers.List.Select(bring => new
        {
            Name = bring._Name,
            Date = bring._Date,
            Position = bring._Position,
        }).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = add;
```

И в классе также есть это: `public void Add(employee add) { list.Add(add); }`
Я добавил в класс для удаления это, но пока не понимаю как правильно реализовать это

```
       public void Remove(employee remove) { list.Remove(remove); }
```

Comment: Как вам [такой вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567) работы с данными?