# Как редактировать пользователей в listview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xml

Скажите пожалуйста, как редактировать и самое главное - сохранять текстбоксы, выбранных пользователей?

Так выглядит процедура добавления

```
private void Add(User user)
    {
        ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(user.Username);
        list.Tag = user;

        lvUsers.Items.Add(list);
    }
```

Так выглядит кнопка сохранения пользователей

```
private void btnSerialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Users users = new Users();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvUsers.Items)
        {
            if (item.Tag != null)
            {
                users.UsersList.Add((User)item.Tag);
            }
        }
        SerializeXML(users);
    }
```

Так выглядит сама форма. Слева добавленные пользователи. Можем выбрать любого, и справа выведутся его данные. Логин и поле с данными. И вот нужно данные справа, редактировать и сохранять обратно в файл.  Файл xml.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас же, при нажатии на Сохранить, конечно ничего не происходит. И я не могу понять, как сохранять данные текстбоксов.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbNukeCode.Text))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tbNukeCode, "Не заполнено поле!");
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbUsername.Text))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tbUsername, "Не заполнено поле!");
        }
        else
        {
            User user = new User(tbUsername.Text, tbNukeCode.Text);
            Add(user);
            ClearInput();
        }
    }
```

Так выглядит код вывода списка пользователей в текстбоксы

```
        private void lvUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvUsers.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            User user = (User)lvUsers.SelectedItems[0].Tag;

            if (user != null)
            {
                tbUsername.Text = user.Username;
                tbNukeCode.Text = user.NukeCode;
            }
        }
        else if (lvUsers.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            ClearInput();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `BindingList` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: На даблклик по списку повесьте обработчик, который загрузит данные в текстбоксы, по кнопке сохранить верните данные в список.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое. Все оказалось через чур просто. Ваш второй коммент помог

Comment: Я хотел ответить на второй ваш вопрос, но вы его удалили. Зачем удалили? Если сами нашли решение - опубликуйте ответ. Если решение не найдено, ждите, отвечают не всегда в первый же день. Если решение нужно позарез, не просто ждите, а обновляйте вопрос, отредактировав его.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov восстановил