# DataGridView, как извлекать данные из БД mysql для конкретной строки Datagridview при нажатии на строку

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть основная форма с `Datagridview` данными. `Datagrdiview` подключен к `Mysql.Datagridview` извлекает информацию из `Mysql`. Дело в том, что на `Datagridview` помещается мало информации, теперь надо чтобы при нажатии на определенную строку открывалась вторая форма, и эта форма извлекала для этой строки данные из БД `Mysql`. Ниже выложил то, что сделано.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;

    namespace LOCAL_PROJECT
    {
     public partial class mary : Form
     {
        public mary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        //CONNECTION STRING
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("sta");
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.168.1.199; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = telecom");
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        int tertip;

        public void spisok()
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(" SELECT* FROM `sta` ", con);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }

        private void mary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            spisok();
            dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 13, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 35;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 12);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 45;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 170;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 160;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 130;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 90;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 78;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 90;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 78;
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width = 140;
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 88;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value ="Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "satstype";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "prefix";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "size";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "freesize";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderCell.Value = "internet_size";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderCell.Value = "freeports";
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderCell.Value = "pots plat";
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderCell.Value = "internet plat";
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderCell.Value = "year";
            dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderCell.Value = "geolocation C";
            dataGridView1.Columns[12].HeaderCell.Value = "geolocation B";
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

            //подсказка для Геолокации
            textBox10.Text = "C";
            textBox10.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            textBox10.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            Font myfont = new Font("Times new Roman", 14);
            textBox10.Font = myfont;

            //подсказка для Геолокации
            textBox11.Text = "B";
            textBox11.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            textBox11.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            Font myfont1 = new Font("Times new Roman", 14);
            textBox11.Font = myfont1;

            
            // SUM 
            textBoxSum.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
            textBoxSumbosgowrum.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[5].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
            textBoxSumInternet.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[6].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
            textBoxSumDslam.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows where row.Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            menu menuu = new menu();
            menuu.Show();
        }

        // Метод автонумерация ID
        private DataTable AutoNumberedTable(DataTable SourceTable)

        {
            DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
            DataColumn AutoNumberColumn = new DataColumn();
            AutoNumberColumn.ColumnName = "tb";
            AutoNumberColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            ResultTable.Columns.Add(AutoNumberColumn);
            ResultTable.Merge(SourceTable);
            return ResultTable;
        }
          
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            string sql = "insert into sta(tb, name, satstype, prefix, size, freesize, internet_size, freeports, potsplata, internetplata, year, geolocationC, geolocationB) Values (null, '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + comboBox1.Text + "',  " +
                "'" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "', '" + textBox9.Text + "', '" + textBox8.Text + "', '" + textBox7.Text + "', '" + textBox12.Text + "', '" + textBox10.Text + "', '" + textBox11.Text + "' )";
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Added!");
            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox6.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox7.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox8.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox9.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox10.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox11.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox12.Text = string.Empty;
            spisok();

        }

        // Метод делете
        private void delete(int tb)
        {
            string sql = "DELETE FROM sta WHERE tb=" + tb + "";
            command = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CON, EXECUTE DELETE, CLOSE CON

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.DeleteCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

                // PROMT FOR CONFIRMATION

                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted!");
                }

                con.Close();

                spisok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Delete button
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            int tb = Convert.ToInt32(selected);
            delete(tb);
        }

       
        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tertip = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

                textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                comboBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                textBox8.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                textBox12.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                textBox10.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                textBox11.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void textBox13_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "Select * From sta where name like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR satstype like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR prefix like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR size like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR freesize like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR internet_size like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR freeports like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR potsplata like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR internetplata like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR year like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR geolocationC like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR geolocationC like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%' OR geolocationB like '%" + textBox13.Text + "%'";
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                command = new MySqlCommand("update sta SET name='" + textBox2.Text + "', sa " +
                    "tstype='" + comboBox1.Text + "', prefix='" + textBox3.Text + "', size='" + textBox4.Text + "', freesize='" + textBox5.Text + "', internet_size='" + textBox6.Text + "', freeports='" + textBox9.Text + "', potsplata='" + textBox8.Text + "', internetplata='" + textBox7.Text + "', year='" + textBox12.Text + "', geolocationC='" + textBox10.Text + "', geolocationC='" + textBox11.Text + "' WHERE tb='" + tertip + "'", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
                con.Close();
                spisok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не храните данные в DGV https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567 обработчик события на двойной клик по ячейке пробовали добавлять? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Master/Detail [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/create-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:** **Некоторые переменные в этом коде могут отличаться от тех, что у вас в БД**. К примеру в строке `string selectedId = dgw1.Rows[dgw.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();` обращение свойству `Cells["Id"]` может вызывать исключение, если в Вашем DGW отсутствует такой столбец. Посмотрите код и исправьте Ваш.

Для начала необходимо получить `Id` конкретного столбца в DataGridView

Для начала создадим обработчик события в котором получим нужную строку `Id`

```
private void dgw1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   string selectedId = dgw1.Rows[dgw.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
   int selectedDgwId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedId);

   //Делаем запрос в БД и получаем какой-то объект. Есть у вас Id в таблице бд называется как-то по-другому, то измените его в запросе.
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE Id = @id", this.connect))
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
      SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      dt.Load(dataReader);
      dr.Close();
 
      Form2 form2 = new Form2(dt ); //Необходимо, чтобы в конструкторе Вашей формы было свойство нужного Вам класса.
   form2.Show();
   }
}
```

Чтобы что-то отобразилось на Form2 (форма которая будет открываться по нажатию на dgw) необходимо изменить её конструктор. Ну и допустим что на форме будет какой-нибудь datagridview (допустим с названием form2dgw)

```
class Form2 : Form
{
   private DataTable _sqlResult;
   public Form2(DataTable sqlResult)
   {
      _sqlResult = sqlResult;
      form2dgw.DataSource = sqlResult;
   }
}
```

Comment: потерялся, не могли бы вы показать пример в моем коде ? я выложу полностью свой код

Comment: Выкладывайте. Как выложите - я отредактирую ответ и тегну Вас

Comment: выложил , помогите пожалуйста, критично важная часть проекта, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на каждую строку открывалась новая окошка и там не важно хоть текстбокс хоть datagrdidview извлекал данные для конкретной строки из БД Mysql

Comment: Вы умеете в ООП? Если да, то советую Вам создать класс модели, которая будет отражать запись в базе данных. Так же, создать отдельный класс, который будет работать с БД. К примеру в этом классе метод ```Insert(MyDbClass obj)``` будет принимать как параметр ```MyDbClass``` (он же класс модели), а в SQL запросе у вас будут просто использоваться свойства этого класса

Comment: ООП данный момент очень печально , просто для себя взялся за проект , хочу довести  до конца , но понимаю что без ООП никуда

Comment: Я добавил изменения в код, прочитайте пожалуйста первый абзац внимательно.

Comment: @jun66 бросайте всё, хотя-бы на 1 вечер и начните учиться, хотя-бы [отсюда](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ).

Comment: @aepot а почему не codeblog? там лысый всё наглядно объясняет, хоть и намного дольше, чем экстримкод

Comment: да согласен, нужно будет пройти весь этот путь , скажите пожалуйста есть реальные подробные примеры применения ООП  на C#Winforms (именно Winforms) а не консольное ? если есть поделитесь пожалуйста , лично сам очень долго искал не нашел . может плохо искал.

Comment: Не знаю на счет примеров, но я не находил, но я уверен, что они есть. Начни с просмотра codeblog, где он ооп начинает объяснять, хорошо объясняет. А дальше начинай играться. создавай TODO-листы, Календарь какой-нибудь. Ну или делай что-то с ООП на интересные тебе темы (например фильм какой-нибудь или игра). Лучше мне кажется самому пытаться что-то делать и потом гуглить каждую вещь, быстрее научишься (имхо)

Comment: понял. я начал именно по его видеоурокам, уроки длинные но понятные,  нравится вот такой видео канал на ютубе XpucT , практично объясняет но ограниченно , последнее время вроде платные видеоуроки вкладывает