# C# сериализация DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, datetimepicker, сериализация

Пытаюсь сохранить данные из TextBox, ComboBox и DateTimePicker'ов в xml файл.

Наткнулся на [статью](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form), всё вроде как сохраняется и потом восстанавливается соответственно, однако при добавлении следующих строк

```
 else if (childCtrl is DateTimePicker) 
   {
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteElementString("Value", ((DateTimePicker)childCtrl).Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
   }
```

в AddChildControls никакого счастья в жизни не происходит. В выходном xml-файле есть записи со значениями введёнными в текстовые поля, выбранными вариантами из боксов.
Однако с dateTimePicker есть только строка про его видимость.

P.S. Происходит всё так - пользователь заполняет поля формы, нажимает "Просмотр", в этот момент происходит сериализация и основное окно закрывается, открывается окно просмотра, пользователь это окно закрывает и возвращается к предыдущему окну, куда происходит десериализация.

Кусочек xml-файла:

```
<Control Type="System.Windows.Forms.Panel" Name="OverallPanel">
    <Visible>True</Visible>
    <Control Type="System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel" Name="OverallLayout">
      <Visible>True</Visible>
      <Control Type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" Name="EngSurnameInput">
        <Text>PETROV</Text>
        <Visible>True</Visible>
      </Control>
      <Control Type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" Name="EngNameInput">
        <Text>Ivan</Text>
        <Visible>True</Visible>
      </Control>
      <Control Type="System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker" Name="DateOfBirthPicker">
        <Visible>True</Visible>
      </Control>
    </Control>
  </Control>
```

P.P.S. Возможно я неправильно ставлю вопрос. В таком случае - буду благодарен за направление в нужные координаты.

Comment: Winforms? XML файл или его фрагмент покажете? Код для воспроизведения проблемы можете написать? Почему XML? Вроде-как не можно уже, все JSON используют, выглядит проще и работает быстрее. Данные в интерфейсе обычно не хранят, для этого используют специальные классы для данных (модели) и сериализуют их. А чтобы интерфейс данные отображал и обновлял в режиме реального времени, используют привязки данных (Data Binding).

Comment: Насколько я вижу, при наличии модели данных, вам в принципе для указанных в посте потребностей, сериализация не потребуется вообще. Пример надо? Если надо, укажите версию .NET.

Comment: Не вставляйте пожалуйста код в комментарий, редактируйте вместо этого сам пост.

Comment: Уважаемый @aepot, Буду отвечать по-порядку:
1. Windows Forms
2. Пример xml закинул в основной пост.
3. Я искал решение своей проблемы, и очень удачно наткнулся именно на ту, старую, статью.
Буду рад поискать иначе - но не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос для поиска (XML, JSON, или что-то ещё)
4. Версия .Net Framework - 4.7.2.

Comment: Уважаемый @aepot, общая суть задачи, которую я пытаюсь решить такая:
Есть две формы. В первой - пользователь вводит данные (Фамилия, Имя, Дата рождения и т.д.), данных этих много. На второй форме отображены все эти данные в едином виде. 
При переходе из первой формы на вторую, первая закрывается, и нужно введенные пользователем данные сохранить. А при переходе из второй на первую, эти данные должны отобразиться в первоначальных местах.

Comment: У меня к сожалению прямо сейчас нет времени писать полноценный ответ, но [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567) я писал ранее. По сути используя ту же самую методику можно применить к любому контролу. Решение вашего вопроса в выбрасывании сериализации из логики вообще, для работы с формами она не нужна. Вместо этого вновь создаваемой форме надо просто передать экземпляр класса с данными, а она привяжется к компонентам. Так как данные будут меняться в классе, вторая форма, получившая этот же экземпляр так же из него же их прочитает.

Comment: Как сериализовать класс или коллекцию экземпляров класса с данными в например JSON, например для сохранения в текстовый файл или передачи по сети, примеров в интернетах полно. Для .NET Framework 4.x есть суперпопулярная библиотека `Newtonsoft.Json`, а для .NET Core 3.x и новее - есть встроенный сериализатор `System.Text.Json`. Делов вам на пару часов, главное - разобраться с методикой привязки данных. Не храните данные в контролах, а только отображайте и возникшая у вас проблема больше никогда не возникнет.

Comment: Фокус с привязкой можно развить до такой степени, что в одной форме вы данные меняете, а в другой в режиме реального времени вы эти изменения сможете видеть даже если обе формы открыты одновременно. Это та гибкость, которую дает данная методика. Хоть 10 форм можно открыть и все для редактирования и в любой можно вносить правки, они будут одновременно видны везде. Магия. :) В WPF эта технология привязки данных вообще родная и без нее выжить там невозможно.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за подсказки. Буду дальше копать в указанном направлении!