# c# Заполнение DataGridView без пустых ячеек

Tags: c#, datagridview

Всем привет. Нужно вставить в dgv значения из Dictionary. Как эти значения правильно вывести в таблицу, чтобы не начиналось каждый раз с новой строки?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я понимаю, что я просто вставляю в новую строку данные. Хотелось-бы узнать, как можно вставлять в ранее созданную строку данные.

Код:

```
            var Dictionary = BusinessMenu.dic;
            foreach (var Product in Dictionary.Values)
            {
                switch (Product.Type)
                {
                    case "Business":
                        dgv.Rows.Add($"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}", null, null, null, null, null);
                        break;
                    case "Salad":
                        dgv.Rows.Add(null, $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}", null, null, null, null);
                        break;
                    case "Soup":
                        dgv.Rows.Add(null, null, $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}", null, null, null);
                        break;
                    case "HotDishes":
                        dgv.Rows.Add(null, null, null, $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}", null, null);
                        break;
                    case "Dessert":
                        dgv.Rows.Add(null, null, null, null, $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}", null);
                        break;
                    case "Drinkable":
                        dgv.Rows.Add(null, null, null, null, null, $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: `в ранее созданную строку данные` - подумайте логически, вам нужна для начала строка, верно? Ну так берите ее из коллекции `dgv.Rows` через индекс, ну или `.Last()`. Строку получили, что дальше? Наверно, нужна ячейка, ок, как по англ. ячейка? `Cell`. Что есть из доступного с таким названием? Наверно `Cells`, что это? Массив? Да. Ну так берем смело через индекс нужную ячейку. Все, присваивайте ей нужное значение. В итоге получаете нечто `dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1] = $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}"`. Ну или сокращенный вариант `dgv[0, 1] = $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}"`. Не ленитесь думать!

Comment: То, что вы написали - это было моей первой идей. Я изначально хотел попробовать dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value, но как я пойму, что данная ячейка является действительно последней и в ней не написано ничего.

Comment: Яж написал `через индекс, ну или .Last()`. Тут идет простая работа с массивами. Будь то `dgv.Rows.Last()`, или `dgv.Rows[dgv.RowCount]`, да даже `dgv.Rows[^1]`, все это даст вам последний объект массива/коллекции. Аналогично с `Cells` (если надо). `не написано ничего` - вы не знаете как проверять на `null` или пустоту? `string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`, если просто на `null`, то `== null` или `is null`.

Comment: Как эти данные изначально попали в Dictionary? Не лучше ли сразу заносить их в правильную структуру данных?

Comment: Чтобы оьметить вопрос решенным, достаточно принять ответ, не нужно редактировать заголовок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov через другую форму, в которой нужно было вписывать эти данные. Данная форма является "предпросмотром". Глобальной нагрузки она не несёт. Нужно было, чтобы просто оно работало. Спасибо

Comment: Спрашиваю ещё раз: как эти данные попадают в Dictionary? Покажите код! Можно задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Создал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347153/c-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал решение. Не очень красиво, с костылями, но работает:

```
dgv.Rows.Add();
FreeIndex = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[5].Value is null)
        {
            dgv.Rows[FreeIndex].Cells[5].Value = $"{Product.Title}/{Product.Price}";
            break;
        }    
        else
        FreeIndex++;
    }
```

и потом, чтоб убрать лишние строки пустые:

```
            var rowsToRemove = new List<int>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                int NullCount = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[column.Index].Value is null)
                        NullCount++;
                }

                if (NullCount == dgv.Columns.Count)
                    rowsToRemove.Add(row.Index);
            }

            rowsToRemove.Reverse();
            rowsToRemove.ForEach(i => dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i));
            rowsToRemove.Reverse();
```

Comment: Жаль, нельзя несколько минусов поставить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov зачем минусить? Можно дать свой правильный ответ.

Comment: @Frehzy А вообще - [вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567), которое может позволить избежать костылей вовсе.

Comment: Тут, я смотрю, класс называется `Product`. Хорошо. Но в нём уже должны быть агрегированные данные. Тогда не понадобится возня с занесением данных в грид и удалением строк.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать обращение к конкретной ячейке.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = "Tets";
```