# Создание словаря с данными о продукте и делением на категории

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, словари

Всем привет. Можно ли как-нибудь красивее написать этот код?

Задача: Создать словарь, в котором будут храниться данные о продукте. Так же, необходимо реализовать деление на категории.

Код:

Класс Builder:

```
class Builder
{
    public Builder(string Type, string Title, int Price, int Index)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Index = Index;

        int i = 0; //ищу свободное место в словаре
        while (BusinessMenu.dic.ContainsKey(i))
            i++;
        BusinessMenu.dic.Add(i, this);
    }

    public string Type { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }
}
```

Класс со словарём:

```
static class BusinessMenu
{
    public static Dictionary<int, Builder> dic = new Dictionary<int, Builder>();
}
```

Добавляю с помощью следующего кода:

```
new Builder(result, TitleTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceTextBox.Text), BusinessCount);
```

где:

- result - соответствующая кнопка, нажатая пользователем, из которой берётся свойство Name и присваивается result. Грубо говоря, это параметр-"Категория"
- TitleTextBox.Text - название продукта
- PriceTextBox.Text - цена продукта
- BusinessCount - Количество продуктов данной категории в списке

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Уточните проблему или посмотрите описание метки [инспекция-кода], плиз.

Comment: Так, возвращаемся к беседе. Имеется класс `Builder`. Хотя речь идёт о продукте, значит класс должен называться `Product`. Ладно. Следует создать коллекцию наподобие `List<Builder> builders` и в неё заносить экземпляры этого класса. Словарь не нужен. Передаём эту коллекцию куда нужно и там используем. В частности, привязываем к гриду: `dataGridView.DataSource = builders`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хотите обратной связи - считайте сами напросились :)

> Создать словарь

Это деталь реализации или требование иметь какое то хранилище для данных?

> BusinessMenu

Почему класс, который называется "Бизнес меню" ничего не делает, кроме как хранит и открывает всему миру свою реализацию?

> public static Dictionary<int, Builder> dic = new Dictionary<int, Builder>();

Публично откывая такую деталь, вы просто пишете в коде "вот словарь, мне не важно кто как и когда имеет к нему доступ, сколько в него было записей и чтений мне тоже не важно, а ещё я согласен, что все клиенты будут знать реализацию моего класса, что я не смогу её сменить никогда. И нпоследок любой клиент класса может делать со словарем все, что угодно, даже просто удалить и новый создать и я не смогу это ни отдебажить ни даже узнать об этом".

Хотите правильно написанный класс - закрывайте реализацию методами.

А, да, у вас ещё и поле статическое, то есть вы заранее связываете все клиенты класса с одним статически инстансом. Это вот зачем? У вас нету DI фреймворка, чтобы ему рассказать, кто сингтон, а кто нет?

> в котором будут храниться данные о продукте

То есть у вас должен быть класс типа `Product` или `ProductData`, который представляет собой данные. Он у вас есть? Нет.

Вместо него у вас какой то `Builder`, который хранит какие то поля. Причем часть публично доступна для изменения, а часть нет - это вот зачем?

А ещё конструктор класса не только конструирует класс, но ещё какой то дополнительной логикой занимается - это для чего? Отделяйте мух от котлет, то есть классы - данные от классов - логики.

Ещё поле Price - целое число? Поле Index - для чего? Почему параметры конструктора у вас с большой буквы?

> while (BusinessMenu.dic.ContainsKey(i))

Вот это вот для чего? Если вы на ходу создаете ключи для словаря, может вам не нужен словарь, а нужен список - у списка же индексы всегда заполнены

Как можно улучшить:

- сделать класс для хранения данных, типа `ProductData` - только поля и констурктор
- сделать словарь в классе `BusinessMenu` приватным, добавить туда методы для добавления продукта или получения или какие вам там методы нужны для управленимя бизнес меню. Сделать его НЕ-статическим, использовать DI если нужен его синглтон
- потенциально поменять словарь на список или что то, что вам больше подходит. Из кода не ясно зачем вообще словарь нужен.
- Поработать над стилем своего кода, см https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/

Comment: Не ожидал такого подробного ответа. Спасибо огромное за обратную связь. 1. Действительно. Даже не подумал над "скрытием" словаря и взаимодействие с ним через методы. 2. DI фреймворка - не особо понял, что это такое. Нашёл информацию, что это расшифровывается, как "dependency injection", и, грубо говоря, представляет собой абстракцию и прочее. Я прав? 3. Часть полей в Builder открыта (set) для их изменения в дальнейшем. Сейчас задумался над "скрытием" их с помощью методов. Постараюсь исправить этот момент. 4. Лучше не пихать логику в конструктор класса? А, например, вызывать метод...

Comment: ...в этом конструкте, в котором будет описана логика этого метода? 5. Мне словарём в такой "проблеме" пользоваться как-то легче что-ли. Привык для больших структур использовать именно его, поэтому и в данном случае применил его. Это считается ошибкой?

Comment: @Frehzy про DI читайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/905310/179763)

Comment: @Frehzy про конструктор. В конструктре логики не должно быть никакой. У вас должен быть метод где то, наподобие `void some_method(){ var product = new ProductData(...); myMenu.Add(product); } `

Comment: `Сейчас задумался над "скрытием" их с помощью методов.` вы используете свойства, которые и представляют собой поле + методы.

Comment: `Мне словарём в такой "проблеме" пользоваться как-то легче что-ли.` пользуйтесь, но сделайте это внутренней деталью реализации класса, чтобы другие классы не знали о словаре. Тогда вы сможете словарь заменить на что хотите + будете контролировать доступ к нему.

Comment: `Это считается ошибкой?` я не знаю, зачем вам тут словарь, потому не могу ответить на это. У вас кроме как привычки есть какая то причина использовать именно словарь?

Comment: Там есть несколько linq, а я привык с ними работать в словаре. В листе это мне сложнее почему-то даётся, поэтому стараюсь его использовать

Comment: @Frehzy нужно работать не с тем, с чем привык, а с тем, что подходит под задачу. Вашу задачу я не знаю,  соответсвенно что под неё подходит я тоже не знаю.

Comment: В любом случае, огромное спасибо, ещё раз. Обязательно проведу переработку кода