# Как создать Detail view для Master view в GridView DevExpress через код

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Пишу код, который работает с таблицей Master-Details.
Мне нужно в коде для таблицы создать Detail view для моего Master View, подскажите как это сделать.
Когда работаешь с контролом, детейл создается в момент первого показа, т.е. когда разворачиваешь мастер вью, а первая строчка создается когда тыкаешь мышкой на пустую строку в детейл вьюшке.
Вот так я пытаюсь получить детейл из мастера:

```
GridView detailSourceView = (GridView) masterSourceView.GetDetailView(
sourceMasterRowHandle, masterSourceView.GetRelationIndex(sourceMasterRowHandle, "CommParts"));
```

Как сделать что бы в этом коде возвращался не null, а новая detail view c нулевым количеством строк?

Comment: А зачем вам это? Вам не должно быть это нужно. Это же winforms?

Comment: Да это вин форм дев экспресс. На самом деле мне это нужно что бы копировать значения из одной таблицы в другую, но я не знаю как копировать значения детейла потому что детейл грид вью в целевой таблице равна null (что логично).

Comment: Храните данные отдельно, не храните их в контролах. Привязывайте данные, чтобы они обновлялись при редактировании из интерфейса, вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567).

Comment: В данной задаче я не имею доступа к интерфейсу, это лишь кусок более сложной интеграции в посторонний продукт. Мне нужно именно в standalone коде сделать такой функционал.

Comment: Значит вы можете рефлексией туда пробраться, найти биндинг и получить из него источник данных. В любом случае забирать данные из контрола - это сложно и неэффективно, и даже не факт что в данном случае возможно.

Comment: Грид вью нет, у него нет ни биндинга, ничего. Он равен null. у него соответственно нет никакого биндина или дата соурса.