# Передать метод GridStyle другим формам

Tags: c#, winforms

уважаемые люди , сколько дней мучаюсь не могу решить проблему , есть 5 одинаковых форм Datagrdiview -ом. между собой отличаются лишь , тем что добавляют и отображают разные таблицы из баз данных. для каждого датагрида создан отдельный метод GridStyle . я хочу использовать только один метод и вызывать на всех 5-и формах. как это реализовать нигде не нашел , ниже выложил сам метод .

```
 public void Gridstyle()
    {
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 13, FontStyle.Bold);
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 35;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 12);
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 45;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 170;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 160;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 130;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 90;
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 78;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 90;
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 78;
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].Width = 140;
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 88;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Id";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "type";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "prefix";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "size";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "freesize";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderCell.Value = "int. size";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderCell.Value = "ds";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderCell.Value = "plata";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderCell.Value = "port";
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderCell.Value = "year";
        dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderCell.Value = "location_c";
        dataGridView1.Columns[12].HeaderCell.Value = "location_b";
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    }
```

Comment: Не создавайте колонки кодом, используйте привязку к модели данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: это же всего лишь оформления ?  в datagridview через конструктор ничего не добавляю , лишь отображается

Comment: спасибо большое ! вызываю этот метод в  private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DgvSetup.Gridstyle(dataGridView1);
        }   но никаких действий не происходит ?  тоесть вообще не грузить Datagrdiview . может я не там вызываю ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, можете создать отдельный класс, назвать его как-нибудь и добавить например статический метод туда.

```
public class DgvSetup
{
    public static void Gridstyle(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        // ...
    }
}
```

И вызывать вот так

```cs
DgvSetup.Gridstyle(dataGridView1);
```

Это хоть и не самое крутое, но самое простое и очевидное решение.

Comment: спасибо большое ! вызываю этот метод в  private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DgvSetup.Gridstyle(dataGridView1);
        }   но никаких действий не происходит ?  тоесть вообще не грузить Datagrdiview . может я не там вызываю ?

Comment: спасибо, да , заработал !

Comment: можно еще один такой же вопрос ?  допустим есть метод подключение Datagrdiview к базе данных , там в параметрах запроса меняется название таблицы базы данных , если я захочу это вывести в отдельный метод , создать класс и запихнуть туда , потом вызову этот метод , как мне придется менять название  таблицы (допустим не management а  
bookkeeping)? выше выложил код , заранее спасибо !

Comment: @Misterjunior отдельный вопрос надо задавать отдельно.

Comment: хорошо , спасибо !