# Как фильтровать DataGridView с помощью TextBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

У меня еще нет большого опыта. Я пытаюсь отфильтровать строки, содержащие вводимый текст. По порядку .. Я использую MailKit для приема входящих сообщений и размещения данных в Grid

```
public void ShowMessages(ImapClient client)
{
    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
    var query = SearchQuery.All;                                                                             
    var uids = inbox.Search(query);
    var items = inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure).Reverse();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
       ...                                 
       dataGridMessages.Rows.Add(read, item.Envelope.Subject, item.Envelope.From, item.Envelope.Date, attach, item.Size, false, item.UniqueId);
    }
}
```

Затем я пытаюсь отфильтровать строки

```
private void searchTxb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataGridMessages.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = string.Format("Subject LIKE '%{0}%'", searchTxb.Text);
    dataGridMessages.DataSource = bs;
}
```

но после набора текста грид пустой, ничего не находит. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы присваиваете `bs.DataSource = dataGridMessages.DataSource;`, потом `dataGridMessages.DataSource = bs;`, потом жмете букву на клавиатуре и процесс повторяется. То есть каждый последующий `bs` указывает на предыдущий `bs`. Получается рекурсивная каша, сингулярность, вселенная схлопывается.

Вы не можете просто так взять строки таблицы и использовать их как источник данных через фильтр для них же самих.

Кстати, при первом присваивании вот здесь

```
bs.DataSource = dataGridMessages.DataSource;
```

Вы чего ожидаете внутри `DataSource`? Строки DGV? Но строки это же не источник данных, а приемник, верно? То есть в `DataSource` будет ровно то, что ранее вы присвоили туда, а если ничего не присвоили, то ничего там и нет, `null`.

Вот так можно выйти из этой проблемной ситуации: [Привязка данных в DataGridView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1199457/373567), а именно перестать использовать строки `DataGridView` как хранилище данных.