# Событие изменения в базе данных Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать.
Суть проблема: У меня есть проект Winform и я использую подключение к БД автоматически создавая EDMX. В проекте есть TabControl и на каждый контрол выведен Grid одной и той же таблицы из БД. Вот модель данных edmx

```
public partial class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdPerson { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data { get; set; }
    public string Nambe { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string RefusalNoticeNambe { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RefusalNoticeData { get; set; }
    public string NoticeNambe { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> NoticeData { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string CerNambe { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CerData { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CetActionIn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CerActionOut { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Deadline { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idVerification { get; set; }
    public string ManagerNotice { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Verification Verification { get; set; }
}
```

При внесении изменений (добавления, удаление или редактирование) в таблицу, хочу сделать событие которое будет следить да методом SaveChanges() и обновлять набор данных на всех Grid.

Comment: С коллекцией `BindingList<T>` знакомы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: @aepot, это не решит в данный момент мою проблему, так как много что переделать придется. Поэтому хотел отследить событие SevingChange(). И передать это событие на другую форму чтоб grid обновил информацию.

Comment: Нет такого события.

Comment: @aepot описался SaveChangesAsync()

Comment: Ситуация та же. Вы можете создать свое событие и вызывать его везде, где вызываете этот метод. В любом случае, это костыль.

Comment: @aepot помогите пожалуйста с написание такого событие( Уже 2 день не могу спать и есть из за этого