# С# windows forms время

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Для записи  и переключения времени в datagridview создал календарь и и спользую его. Дану записывает нормально,но теперь нужно еще и записывать время.Но по чему то время всегда записывает только полдень . Что можно сделать ?

```
        private void Calend_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {  
        thisDay = DateTime.Parse(Calend.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        textData.Text = thisDay;
        Reload_Data();
    }
```

Comment: помемняте `hh` на `HH`

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, как сделать что бы время обновлялось при изменении ячейки?

Comment: Время где? Ячейки чего? [Оно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567)?

Comment: В datagridview c# есть записи и я их могу добавлять,время добавляется автомотом . Мне нужно что бы при изменении datagridview  в ячейке в datagridview  менялось время тоже автоматом