# Как передать строку из datagridview1 по нажатию на кнопку в datagridview2

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку продать данная строка переносилась в datagridview2,помогите пожалуйста .и еще проблемка с растягиванием столбцов ,как их растянуть ?

у меня есть запрос в форме  и обработчик нажатия на кнопку продать

```
private void Shops_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                p = "Продукция";
                string query1 = "SELECT ID,Title,ArticleNumber,MinCostForAgent FROM Product_KP ";
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = con.ConDS(query1).Tables[0];
                DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                
                col.Text = "Продать";
                col.Name = "Продажа";
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
                col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            }
    
            private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    
    
                if (dataGridView1.Columns [e.ColumnIndex].Name== "Продажа")
                {
                   
                }
    
    
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567 берете 2 BindingList, привязываете к 2 DGV, при нажатии на кнопку из одного списка удалчете элемент, в другой добавляете. Проще не придумаешь.

Comment: А нельзя просто прописать код для кнопки чтобы передавал всю строку в другой датагридвьюв?

Comment: Это будет сложнее, чем я предлагаю. А потому почему бы вам не научиться работать с данными правильно? В вашем случае BindingList заменяет DataTable, уже все, так сказать, готово. Создайте вторую DataTable, накидайте в нее таких же колонок. При нажатии забирайте DataRow и уносите во вторую DataTable.

Comment: А как забирать DataRow и уносить во вторую DataTable?

Comment: Индекс строки вам известен, так? Берете строку из DataTable по индексу, это и есть DataRow. Вот такое заклинание `DataTable dt = (DataTable)((DataGridView)sender).DataSource;` `DataRow row = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];` `dt2.ImportRow(row);`

Comment: Спасибо но dt2 он не видит,видимо надо создать

Comment: Я же вам выше писал "создайте вторую DataTable...". Так же в `Shops_Load` событии, скопируйте туда колонки из первой таблицы. И таскайте строки туда-сюда, сколько угодно. :) DGV сама покажет все изменения. Положите вторую либо в поле класса формы, либо так же можно ее из DataSource второй DGV достать. Но сначала конечно ее туда надо положить. :)