# Вывод класса в dgv

Tags: c#, datagridview

Всем привет.

Есть класс Person, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Person() { }

    public Person(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Products = new Dictionary<int, Product>();
    }

    public List<Product>? GetProducts() => (Products?.Values ?? Enumerable.Empty<Product>()).ToList();
}
```

У Product есть поля: Guid Id, string Name, decimal Price

Суть задачи: необходимо вывести в DGV List по следующей картине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прогуглив, нашёл, что через BindingSource вполне можно легко добавлять элементы в DGV. Через foreach цикл добавляю элементы в BindingSource и затем устанавливаю для DGV свойство DataSource = BindingSource. Всё классно, но Dictionary<int, Product> отображается, как *коллекция*. Как можно отобразить значения этого словаря?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567 + посмотрите режим Master/Details у DataGridView

Comment: Выглядит страшно, но попробую разобраться. Спасибо за наводку, куда копать