# Как передать в конструктор класса ссылку на объект, например передать DataGridView в конструктор

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть класс в котором хранятся обработанные данные, в этот класс добавил метод который выбирает нужные данные из этого класса и выводит в DataGridView.  Как теперь правильно добавить ссылку в конструктор класса например на DataGridView1, чтобы при создании экземпляра этого класса я сразу же добавлял DataGridView с которым нужно работать? В C# я новичек, но знаю хорошо просто язык СИ.

```
  class CAN_Sniffer_Rx
    {
        public CAN_Sniffer_Rx( DataGridView dg)
        {
            _button_rx_on_off = false;
            _number_of_last_line= 0;
            dgvw = dg;
        }
        public uint[] _id = new uint[max_message];
        public byte[] _dlc = new byte[max_message];
        public byte[,] _data  = new byte[max_message,8];
        public ushort[] _message_counter = new ushort[max_message];
        public ushort[] _message_period = new ushort[max_message];
        public byte _number_of_last_line;
        //public byte _number_of_current_line;

        public bool _button_rx_on_off;
        private DataGridView dgvw;

         public void CAN_Prlc_Show_in_the_dG()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _number_of_last_line; i++)//
            {
                //Invoke(new Action(() =>
                //{
                    if (dgvw.RowCount < _number_of_last_line) dgvw.Rows.Add(); //добавляем поля

                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = _id[i].MyConvertToHEX();
                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = _dlc[i];
                    for (byte cell = 3, p = 0; p < 8; cell++, p++)
                    {
                        dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[cell].Value = _data[i,p].MyConvertToHEX();
                    }
                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = _message_counter[i];
                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = _message_period[i];
                    dgvw.Update();
//                   }));

            }
        }
    }

    CAN_Sniffer_Rx can_sniffer_rx = new CAN_Sniffer_Rx(dataGrid_CAN1);
```

Comment: Этот код выглядит нормально. Уточните проблему.

Comment: Вообще я вам рекомендую освоить привязки данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567, будет гораздо проще жить.

Comment: Немного посидев разобрался и все скомпилировалось, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

С начала начну не с самой ошибки, а с кода.

1. Замените массивы на класс и массив этого класса.
2. В C# не принято разделять слова с помощью _, как это в Java или в Си, используйте "_numberOfLastLine", вместо "_number_of_last_line"

Для решения проблемы вам нужен отдельный публичный класс / статичный класс, в моём решении я для удобства использую статичный класс.

File User.cs:

```
using static Wrapper;
public class User
{
    public uint ID { get; set; }
    public byte DLC { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; } = new byte[8];
    public ushort MessageCounter { get; set; }
    public ushort MessagePeriod { get; set; }
}
```

File CanSnifferRx.cs:

```
using static Wrapper;
class CANSnifferRx
{
    public CANSnifferRx(DataGridView dg)
    {
        buttonRxOnOff = false;
        numberOfLastLine = 0;
        dgvw = dg;
    }
    public User[] users = new User[numberOfLastLine]();
    public byte numberOfLastLine;

    public bool buttonRxOnOff;
    private DataGridView dgvw;

    public void CAN_Prlc_Show_in_the_dG()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLastLine; i++)
        {
            User user = users[i];
            if (dgvw.RowCount < numberOfLastLine) dgvw.Rows.Add();

            dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
            dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = user.ID.MyConvertToHEX();
            dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = user.DLC;
            for (byte cell = 3, p = 0; p < 8; cell++, p++)
            {
                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[cell].Value = user.Data[i, p].MyConvertToHEX();
            }
            dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = user.MessageCounter;
            dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = user.MessagePeriod;
            dgvw.Update();
        }
    }
}

CANSnifferRx canSnifferRx = new CANSnifferRx(dataGridCAN1);
```

File Wrapper.cs:

```
public static class Wrapper
{
   public static DataGridView dgvw = new DataGridView ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Yotic, изначально я просто добавил класс со статическими полями и данные с буфера просто пихал туда, типо как в структуру на языке СИ, но сам понимал что не правильно делаю, но данные в дата грид с буфера выводились и выводятся, результат есть. Сейчас задумал добавить еще один дата грид и выводить еще одни данные на основе этого класса(читать две линии CAN-шины одновременно)
Изначально было вот так, отдельный метод сюда запихивал данные, другой в отдельном потоке читал их из этого класса:

```
class CAN_RX_Class
{
    static public uint[] Id = new uint[max_message];
    static public byte[] DLC = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte0 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte1 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte2 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte3 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte4 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte5 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte6 = new byte[max_message];
    static public byte[] Byte7 = new byte[max_message];
    static public ushort[] CAN_count = new ushort[max_message];
    static public ushort[] CAN_period = new ushort[max_message];
    static public ushort number_last_string;
   // static public ushort current_line_number = 0;
}
```

А это результат сегодняшнего труда. Создаю экземпляр этого класса и запихиваю туда данные с _bufer, далее в этом классе есть метод который распихивает по полочкам данные, и метод который выводит во внесенный в него в качестве параметра датагрид, теперь на основании этого, могу создать еще экземпляр и обработать еще одни отдельные данные:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CAN_Sniffer_Rx can_sniffer_rx = new CAN_Sniffer_Rx(); //экземпляр класса ******************************************************************************

    bool FlagBtnStartStopClick, FlagBtnSendToCAN;
    bool FlagBtnOpenClick;

    private const int DataSize = 256;    //  число в байтах
    private static readonly byte[] _bufer = new byte[DataSize];
    private int _stepIndex;
    private bool _startRead;
    private const ushort maxMessage = 256;
    private const byte firstFiveByte = 5;
    private const byte sizeOfcrc = 4;//4 байта CRC
    private const byte sizeOfStartsByte = 5;//5 байт начальных
    private byte rowIndexDataGridCAN1click = 0;//по щелчку ячейки сюда попадают значения
    private bool microcontrolerBusy = false, recordErrorCRC = false, sendCANmsgBusy = false;

    class CAN_Sniffer_Rx
    {
        public CAN_Sniffer_Rx()
        {
            _ButtonRxOnOff = false;
            _NumberOfLastLine = 0;
        }
        public uint[] _id = new uint[maxMessage];
        public byte[] _dlc = new byte[maxMessage];
        public byte[,] _data = new byte[maxMessage, 8];
        public ushort[] _MessageCounter = new ushort[maxMessage];
        public ushort[] _MessagePeriod = new ushort[maxMessage];
        public byte _NumberOfLastLine;

        public bool _ButtonRxOnOff;

        public void CAN_Prlc_Show_in_the_dG(ref DataGridView dgvw)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _NumberOfLastLine; i++)//
            {

                if (dgvw.RowCount < _NumberOfLastLine) dgvw.Rows.Add(); //добавляем поля

                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = _id[i].MyConvertToHEX();
                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = _dlc[i];
                for (byte cell = 3, p = 0; p < 8; cell++, p++)
                {
                    dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[cell].Value = _data[i, p].MyConvertToHEX();
                }
                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = _MessageCounter[i];
                dgvw.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value = _MessagePeriod[i];
                dgvw.Update();
            }
        }
        
        public void CAN_Sniffer_handler()
        {
            //начальный массив для проверки по id >>
            uint ID_array = 0;
            for (byte j = 5, offset = 28; j <= 12; j++, offset -= 4)
                ID_array += (uint)((_bufer[j].MyAsciiToHex()) << offset);
            //<<
            for (ushort i = 0; i <= _NumberOfLastLine; i++)
            {

                if (ID_array == _id[i])
                {

                    //Формируем DLC
                    _dlc[i] = (byte)(((_bufer[13].MyAsciiToHex()) << 4) + (_bufer[14].MyAsciiToHex()));
                    //Формируем DATA
                    for (byte s = 15, t = 0; t < 8; s += 2, t++)
                        _data[i, t] = (byte)(((_bufer[s].MyAsciiToHex()) << 4) + (_bufer[s + 1].MyAsciiToHex()));
                    //формируют Counter
                    _MessageCounter[i] = 0;
                    for (byte j = 31, offset = 12; j <= 34; j++, offset -= 4)
                        _MessageCounter[i] += (ushort)((_bufer[j].MyAsciiToHex()) << offset);
                    //формируем period
                    _MessagePeriod[i] = 0;
                    for (byte j = 35, offset = 12; j <= 38; j++, offset -= 4)
                        _MessagePeriod[i] += (ushort)((_bufer[j].MyAsciiToHex()) << offset);
                    break;
                }
                else if (i == _NumberOfLastLine)
                {
                    //формируем ID
                    _id[i] = ID_array;
                    //Формируем DLC
                    _dlc[i] = (byte)(((_bufer[13].MyAsciiToHex()) << 4) + (_bufer[14].MyAsciiToHex()));
                    //Формируем DATA
                    for (byte s = 15, t = 0; t < 8; s += 2, t++)
                        _data[i, t] = (byte)(((_bufer[s].MyAsciiToHex()) << 4) + (_bufer[s + 1].MyAsciiToHex()));
                    //формируют Counter
                    _MessageCounter[i] = 0;
                    for (byte j = 31, offset = 12; j <= 34; j++, offset -= 4)
                        _MessageCounter[i] += (ushort)((_bufer[j].MyAsciiToHex()) << offset);
                    //формируем period
                    _MessagePeriod[i] = 0;
                    for (byte j = 35, offset = 12; j <= 38; j++, offset -= 4)
                        _MessagePeriod[i] += (ushort)((_bufer[j].MyAsciiToHex()) << offset);
                    //инкрементируем строку
                    _NumberOfLastLine++;
                    break;

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Но почитав ваше сообщение @Yotic, понял что это тоже не то, попробую как-то еще разнести массивы в отдельный класс

> Замените массивы на класс и массив этого класса.

Пока не совсем понятно, изучу ваш пример, спасибо.

[image: Тестовые сообщения выводятся, как и с прошлым вариантом]