# Как создать массив из разных элементов формы?

Tags: c#, .net

Я использовал в своем коде функцию, которая содержала в себе массив TextBox'ов и при вызове ее возвращала мне этот массив в любом участке кода.

```
private TextBox[] textBoxArray() 
{
   TextBox[] array = {tb1,tb2,tb3,tb4,tb5};
   return array;
}
```

Это нужно было, чтобы работать в циклах со всеми textBox'ами кратко.

```
private void openTextBox() 
{
   for (int i; i < textBoxArray().Length;i++) 
        textBoxArray()[i].Enabled = true;

}
```

С помощью этого я мог заполнить все textBox'ы данными из dataGridView

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        textBoxArray()[i].Text = dgv[i, rowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Теперь на моей форме появились comboBox'ы и dateTimePicker'ы и они находятся между textbox'ами. Заполнять последовательно с помощью такого массива не получается. Не подскажите что можно еще использовать для реализации обращения ко всем разом?
Мне кажется, что обращаться к каждому по отдельности неправильно.
Я пробовал создавать массив из object, но object не содержит Enabled

Comment: Зачем вам Enabled у каждого? Если надо выключить все, можно Enabled задать у родителя. Поместите все контролы в любую панель и работайте с ней. По-хорошему, вам бы привязку данных освоить. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: Вообще у всех контролов есть общий родитель `Control`, следовательно можно создать массив `Control[]`.

Comment: @aepot, действительно, я смог создать общий массив с Control[]. Это помогло. Заинтересовали по поводу привязки данных. Обязательно узнаю. Благодарю.