# Как связать значение свойства/поля класса с свойством контрола?

Tags: c#, winforms, ref

Я хочу поместить ссылку на строку в класс

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public ref string Value; //компилятор говорит, что так нельзя
    //...
}
```

чтобы сделать так:

```cs
MyClass foo = new();
foo.Value = ref SomeTextbox.Text;
SomeTextbox.Text = "something" //допустим, пользователь что-то вводит
MessageBox.Show(foo.Value) //"something"
```

В моём случае, области видимости (и, соответственно, время жизни) текстбокса и моего класса одинаковы. Поэтому, хотелось бы задать `Value` в качестве ссылки на текстбокс. Можно ли это сделать?
Я знаю об альтернативных решениях с использованием:

- Обработчиков событий `TextChanged` или `LostFocus`
- `Tag`

но мне просто интересна сама возможность использования ссылки внутри класса, как правильно её внутри класса объявлять и как назначать. И если поле другого класса совсем невозможно использовать в качестве ссылки, то вопрос всё равно актуален – как тогда поместить ссылку на `TextBox`.. или вообще любую другую (текстбокс здесь для примера) внутрь динамического класса?

Например `foo.Value = ref SomeExampleString` – как я должен объявить `Value` в классе, чтобы это работало?

Comment: Это winforms или wpf? Если да, то есть другой способ. А с `ref` ничего не получится.

Comment: А как это сделать с помощью свойств? Изменю название вопроса, поскольку на момент написания забыл как называются свойства

Comment: Я дам решение, если скажете тип прилодения.

Comment: это winforms, добавлю тег

Comment: @AlexF Несуществующую функцию? Это какую? А data binding выглядит подходяще. Если я правильно понимаю, то если я добавлю `SomeTextbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", foo.Value, "Name");`, изменение текста текстбокса повлечет за собой изменение foo.Value, так?

Comment: @Титан вот только не надо пытаться передать `foo.Value` в биндинг по значению, это не может работать! И откуда вы вообще взяли "Name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `ref` не получится, так как свойство контрола не является полем. Получится через привязку данных.

Сначала надо реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, например в базовом классе.

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Теперь код вашего класса изменить вот так

```
public class MyClass : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string value;

    public string Value
    {
        get => value;
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Создам форму, на которой будет `Label` и `Button`. Назначу 2 обработчика `Form1.Load` и `Button.Click`, получится вот такой код.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private MyClass data;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data = new MyClass();
        label1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(Label.Text), data, nameof(MyClass.Value));
        // эквивалент label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Value");
    }
}
```

Теперь при изменении свойства `Value` у класса, текст в метке изменится автоматически.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом не следует напрямую обращаться к `label1.Text` и не следует обращаться к полю `value` у класса с данными вне геттера и сеттера свойства `Value`. То есть из кода можно обращаться только к свойству `MyClass.Value`, тогда все привязанные к нему контролы будут своевременно обновляться.

Более сложные случаи привязок для Winforms я рассматривал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567).

Comment: Спасибо, и это также изменит data.Value при вводе пользователем текста в текстбокс (если привязать данные к текстбоксу)?

Comment: @Титан совершенно верно, изменит. Но я не помню, по какому именно событию, скорее всего по лост-фокусу. В WPF это настраивается, в винформах - не помню.