# C# - Как округлить число до целого

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет.

Написал программу погоды, которая считывает данные по API с сайта https://api.openweathermap.

Данные, отображаются в моей программе c точкой (с дробной частью):

[image: скриншот программы]

Я хочу, чтоб данные округлялись и выводились целым числом (как, например, `byte` или `int`).

Я понимаю, что нужно писать примерно так:

```
label1.Text = match.Groups[3].Value + " " + ((int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(match.Groups[1].Value))).ToString();
```

но этот код не работает.

Полный код метода:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string line = "";
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        line = wc.DownloadString($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={textBox1.Text}&units=metric&appid");
   Match match = Regex.Match(line, "\"temp\":(.*?),(.*?)\"name\":\"(.*?)\",");
   label1.Text = match.Groups[3].Value + " " + `match.Groups[1].Value` + " °C";                    
}
```

Comment: **1.** `WebClient` устарел, это можно понять, зайдя на офф сайт и прочитав, что его заменой теперь является `HttpClient`. **2.** Вы получаете JSON, который бредово парсить регулярками, ибо для этого есть специальные механизмы, называющиеся "десериализацией", в современном C# есть для этого `System.Text.Json`. Делайте класс, в нем описывайте всю структуру JSON и десериализуйте в этот класс. **3.** Зачем вам тут матиматика, конвертация, и прочее, если вы выводите это все в `string`? Пишите значит формат, C# сам вам все округлит, например `label1.Text = $"{4.84:F0}";`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать делать так:  $"{4.84:F0}"
Подскажите пожалуйста, а что это такое? (F0)
Я, видь новичок и только учусь

Comment: Если я правильно все понимаю, то мне нужно сделать так:
label1.Text = match.Groups[3].Value + " " + {match.Groups[1].Value: F0} + " °C";
в моём коде

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1407823/373567 вот ещё что есть, пригодится

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать.

Answer (score 1):

### Как округлить дробное число?

###### Вариант №1 - округление на уровне данных:

```
double x = 0.5d;
int result = (int)Math.Round(x);
```

Этот вариант стоит использовать в том случае, если вам необходимо проводить какие-то дальнейшие действия в коде над округлённым числом.

###### Вариант №2 - округление на уровне [форматирования](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f):

```
double x = 0.5d;
string result = $"{x:F0}";
```

Этот вариант стоит использовать в том случае, если вам необходимо сделать красивое представление числа для вывода.

**P.S.**

Также крайне советую прислушайтесь к советам из комментария @EvgeniyZ.

Comment: вероятно стоит вспомнить что есть несколько вариантов округления - всегда в большую сторону, всегда в меньшую и математически коректное округление

Comment: Спасибо, я видь новичок и только учусь, вообще-то хочу в своём коде поменять, не переписывая код.
буду пробовать так:  $"{x:F0}"

Comment: Если я правильно все понимаю, то мне нужно сделать так: label1.Text = match.Groups[3].Value + " " + {match.Groups[1].Value: F0} + " °C"; в моём коде? правильно или нет?

Comment: @Aleksey сначала пробуйте, потом спрашивайте. Но нет, это неправильно, читайте про интерполяцию строк, а то у вас каша получилась `label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value):F0} °C";`. Ну и верно говорят, парсить JSON регулярками - зло.

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать дальше

Comment: @Aleksey если ответ был полезен, вы можете его принять, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Это моя одна из первых программ, по этому учусь, и задаю может быть "глупые вопросы".
label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value):F0} °C";  написал так, но у меня в программе результат тот же. Не получилось целое число.
https://i.imgur.com/cjXI6yN.png
https://i.imgur.com/IwPBVUe.png

Comment: @Aleksey у вас на фото отсутствует  `"...double.Parse(...)..."`

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA я думал об этом, но тут вопрос про обычное математическое округление, по-этому не стал дополнять ответ "полом" и "потолком"

Comment: @iiKuzmychov  
ваш пример
double x = 0.5d;
string result = $"{x:F0}";      в примере понятно. 
Мне не понятно что делать в моём примере? т.е. я понимаю что мне надо конвертировать вот это (match.Groups[1].Value) , но конкретно значение (Value) из этой группы (1).
Я написал уже код по подсказкам (все кто подсказывал тут)
label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value):F0} °C";     и всё равно не работает с таким кодом, программа.
Вопрос, где моя ошибка в этом коде? Понимаю, что топчусь на одном месте, но никто пока не подсказал, чтоб заработала программа.

Comment: Еще дополню:  единственное в вашем примере 
double x = 0.5d; string result = $"{x:F0}";
мне не понятно, так это F0 - что это означает?
Нужно ли применять $"{x:F0}"; в моём примере?   Я стараюсь писать мой вопрос, так чтоб было понятно,  всем, что мне надо сделать в программе, чтоб она работала правильно. 
Но так, чтоб  не переписывать ничего, а только менять в этой строке  label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value):F0} °C";    и чтоб программа заработала, если так нельзя решить, то просто скажите, что бы не меняй тут, не заработает, потому что .......

Comment: `F0` это форматирование числа, которое позволяет округлить число до 0 знаков после запятой, то есть до целого числа. Я вам не просто так добавил ссылку на слово `форматирования` в тексте ответа, перейдите по ней

Comment: если ваша строка кода теперь выглядит так: `label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value):F0} °C"` и у вас всё равно что то не работает - обновите вопрос, добавив в него описание новой проблемы и ошибки

Comment: Извините, сразу не увидел что это ссылка, сейчас с F0 - стало понятно.
Вот пожалуйста, снял видео ошибки
https://www.upload.ee/download/14952868/ebc1f677136b1c7952ec/Video_2023-02-20_020320.mp4
Спасибо вам, что подсказываете и помогаете.

Comment: помогли на другом ресурсе, как написать код, что бы он работал:
label1.Text = $"{match.Groups[3].Value} {(int)Math.Round(double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))} °C";
задача по моему вопросу закрыта, этот код работает и это, то что надо