# Как передавать переменные из класса в другой класс

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп

Перешел на Microsoft Forms. Пишу программку на c#. Все делаю ради учения.
Сделал я кнопочку на Windows Forms, при нажатии на нее я могу открывать диалог и выбирать путь к папки или файлу. А потом этот путь записывается в textBox.

Вот скриншот Windows Forms:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит код:

```
 public string foldername;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, 
        EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foldername = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Text = foldername;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender,
        EventArgs e){}
```

Что я хочу сделать? Как наверное я понимаю, весь путь храниться в переменной "foldername".
Дак вот, если же это так. То как мне использовать эту переменную в другом классе?
Весь код который я показал выше, храниться в классе Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{/*-- Храниться код который показан выше --*/}
```

А вот в каком классе я хочу использовать переменную foldername:

```
internal class ScanningFile{/*-- Класс где должна использоваться переменная foldername --*/}
```

К примеру в классе ScanningFile, данная переменная foldername будет использоваться для нахождение файла txt по назначенному ей пути. После нахождение txt файлика в другую переменную к примеру в folderResult которая создана в классе ScanningFile будет записываться результат. Наверное вы
меня поняли. И уже после всех этих манипуляция, переменная folderResult будет записываться в класс Form1 и там допустим будет с помощью ее отображать результат в listBox.

Я не прошу показывать как сделать нахождение txt файлов. Я хочу вызывать переменную в другом классе а после этого возвращать ее в родной класс где она и создавалась.

Может кто небудь подскажет как это сделать? Если я ошибаюсь в том что я написал выше,  точнее в том что возможно ли это делать, то можете ли вы мне подсказать другой способ как работать с классами и ихими переменными?

Comment: Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то... Если Ваш класс зависит от каких-то данных, то это называется зависимость и в идеальном случае должен передаваться параметром в конструктор при создании экземпляра - new ScanningFile(foldername). Т.е. Вы создаёте экземпляр класса, передав параметром в конструктор необходимые данные, затем вызываете нужные Вам методы, среди которых может быть и тот метод, который вернёт Вам результат какого-то действия. Также почитайте про MVP (WinForms) и MVVM (WPF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что хотелось-бы отметить - предлагаю передавать не переменную, а класс. В таком случае, если вы будете дорабатывать код, не придётся менять существующий. Нужно будет лишь добавить новое свойство в класс и сделать действия для него.

Пример класса:

```
public class Folder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _folderName;

    public string FolderName
    {
        get => _folderName;
        set
        {
            _folderName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FolderName));
        }
    }

    public Folder(string folderName)
    {
        FolderName = folderName;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

У нас происходит передача в конструктор класса переменной типа string, в которой хранится folderName. Для создания экземпляра такого класса воспользуйтесь следующей конструкцией:

```
var folderName = "";
var folder = new Folder(folderName); //пример передачи данных через конструктор
```

Итак, мы сделали класс, в котором хранится какая-то информация о папке. Дальше, нам нужно привязать этот класс (точнее свойство этого класса) к textBox. Зачем? Существуют некоторые паттерны в программировании, которые говорят "Чувак, пользуйся привязкой данных. Это круто". Пример таких паттернов: MVVM, MVP и прочие.

Реализация привязки данных:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Folder _folder = new(default);

    public Form1() =>
        InitializeComponent();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(nameof(TextBox.Text), _folder, nameof(_folder.FolderName), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            _folder.FolderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Итак, мы создаём ПОЛЕ _folder, в котором хранится экземпляр класса Folder. Во время загрузки формы мы создаём привязку свойства Text у TextBox к СВОЙСТВУ FolderName экземпляра класса Folder (_folder).

Далее, создаём некоторую логику обновления данного свойства (button1_Click).

Как же теперь дальше:

Допустим, у нас есть Form2, в которую нужно передать данный параметр:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Folder _folder;

    public Form2(Folder folder) //передача параметра
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _folder = folder;
    }
}
```

Допустим, у нас есть метод, в который нужно передать данный параметр:

```
public void DoSome(Folder folder) //передача параметра
{
    /* logic */
}

DoSome(new Folder(default));
```

---

UPD:

Давайте представим, что мы всё же решили отказаться от привязок и сделать всё в лоб. Почистим код от привязок и добавим прямое присвоение свойству Text класса textBox1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Folder _folder = new(default);

    public Form1() =>
        InitializeComponent();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _folder.FolderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Text = _folder.FolderName;
        }
    }
}
```

Либо, вообще создадим ивент изменения свойства:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Folder _folder = new(default);

    public Form1() =>
        InitializeComponent();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            _folder.FolderName = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Что мы имеем в итоге? Код гораздо меньше, меньше нужно запариваться и вообще вертел всё это ООП и паттерны. Тогда, что же будет, если вы решите чуть расширить свой код? Вам придётся опять писать "textBox1.Text = " или создавать для каждого textBox ивент на обновление Text. И так каждый раз.

А теперь представьте, что в команде вы работаете не один и какой-нибудь Вася будет так же, как и вы сидеть над кодом и так же будет посылать все эти концепции и паттерны подальше к Алану Кэю и Дядюшке Бобу. И, конечно, он будет писать везде "textBox1.Text = " или вообще создаст ивент textBox1.Change, как я писал выше. А если textBox будет несколько? И вот сейчас представьте количество ЛИШНЕГО кода, которое будет расти и расти у вас.

Вывод: Привязка - не такая сложная штука. Реализовать её можно по этому примеру буквально минут за 5. Это сильно уменьшит количество кода, повысит его читаемость и добавит немного баллов в копилку вашей кармы для человека, который будет потом в вашем коде копаться.

Comment: он сейчас может это не понять, лучше не отпугивать)) В ТЗ ключевое:
"Пишу программку на c#. Все делаю ради учения."
Автор, это решение правильнее моего, но не пугайся если чего-то не поймёшь)

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Как мне кажется, код нужно учиться писать сразу правильно, чтобы через какое-то время не стало открытием, что передавать данные лучше через параметры, а не через статику. Я постарался максимально подробно расписать каждое действие. В случае возникновения каких-либо вопросов не стесняйтесь их задавать

Comment: Я люблю привязки, но в данном конкретном случае кроме освоения технологии, в них практической пользы нет. Если вы хотите показать технологию, сначала покажите новичку решение "в лоб", а потом расскажите, почему предлагаемое вами решение лучше, чем `.Text =`.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Добавил пояснений, почему стоит использовать привязки

Comment: @Frehzy, Здравствуйте! Спасибо вам за ответ и все кто тоже мне помогал, спасибо.
Буду тогда пробовать использовать привязки. Правда вот к сожалению для меня это пока что сложно. К примеру я все же не понял, для чего нужен INotifyPropertyChanged. Сам же я пробую сделать так: internal class Folder : INotifyPropertyChanged но у меня выдает ошибку о том что такой тип не удалось найти.  Что мне в этом случаи нужно сделать?

Comment: Пропишите using System.ComponentModel; вместе со всеми using (вверху). А так, в случае появляения таких ошибок, наводите на ошибку, кликайте по ней и нажимайте Alt+Enter и выбирайте то, что вам нужно

Comment: Если вам помог какой-то ответ - нажмите галочку возле него и стрелку вверх

Comment: @Frehzy, А можете мне написать где по подробнее узнать о том что такое привязки? Если же конечно вы это знаете.

Comment: @ZigDDa До меня дошло, когда только начинал изучать эту тему, после просмотра вот этого видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOf2FZ6dkbU. Я долго не мог понять, что это за хрень и как это использовать. Конечно, тут про wpf рассказывают, но в winforms аналогично почти всё. Вот ещё немного полезных ссылок https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/11.php. В конце концов, всегда можно загуглить "c# binding wpf/winforms"

Comment: @ZigDDa https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Answer (score 1):

1. В классе Form1 создать переменную "currentFolderName" и передавать в неё значение из textBox
2. В классе ScanningFile создать переменную "folderName"
3. В классе ScanningFile создать конструктор, принимающий строку и инициализирующий ей поле folderName
4. При создании экземпляра ScanningFile передавать в него currentFolderName

---

```
new ScanningFile(currentFolderName);
```