# Запись данных в DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Мне нужно чтобы я в программе вводил данные и они сохранялись в таблице SQL.
Вот код, который работает, но только для тех таблиц, где имеется ячейки с типом INT, а у меня таблица только с типами STRING.
Подскажите команду для применения данной функции для таблиц, где нет типов INT.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database.openConnection();

        var mail = textBox1.Text;
        int oplata;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out oplata))
        {
            var addQuery = $"insert into shops (mail, pay) values ('{mail}','{oplata}')";

            var command = new SqlCommand(addQuery, database.GetConnection());
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Запись успешно создана!", "Успех!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Запись должна иметь цифровой формат!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        database.closeConnection();
    }
```

Comment: `int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out oplata)` - велосипед какой-то :) , делай сразу так - `int oplata = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text);`

Comment: `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` возвращает количество затронутых записей в бд, в твоем случае `ExecuteNonQuery` должен возвращать цифру 1, так как ты вставляешь одну запись. Попробуй в отладке посмотреть что возвращает эта функция (`int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();`)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Ничего не понятно типы полей в бд должны соответствовать тому, что вы в них пытаетесь записать. Про датагрид тоже самое. Поизучайте DataAdapter + DataTable, сможете проще связать базу и таблицу в интерфейсе. Но лучше работать с моделями данных в классах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567, их проще связать с бд используя ORM библиотеку, например Entity Framework, тогда вообще SQL запросы руками писать не надо будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database.openConnection();

    var mail = textBox1.Text;
    var addQuery = $"insert into shops (mail) values ('{mail}')";

    var command = new SqlCommand(addQuery, database.GetConnection());
    int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Запись успешно создана!", "Успех!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    MessageBox.Show("Запись должна иметь цифровой формат!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    database.closeConnection();
}
```