# Как из реестра вытащить названия программ и записать их в определенный столбец бд?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Я делаю следующее: я в реестре направляюсь в

> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

потом вытаскиваю оттуда некоторую информацию о программах и хочу поместить ее в бд

1. Когда я вытаскиваю названия программ, некоторые из них отображаются как-то странно, примерно так:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как это можно исправить?
вот код того как я беру инфу:

```
private void Glavnoe_okno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey Namekey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (string Key in Namekey.GetSubKeyNames())
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Key);
    }
```

2. Как тогда мне переделать данный код, чтобы взять другие параметры, например "DisplayVersion" или "Publisher"?
3. Каким образом тогда должен выглядеть шаблон на добавление в таблицу БД, чтобы названия программ писались в один столбец, разработчик - во второй, а версия - в третий?

Comment: А при чем тут `sql-server`?

Comment: База данных, в которую данные надо перенести - sql-server как раз

Comment: А что туда переносить? Копию реестра? Так данные уже сохранены в реестре, какой смысл их куда-то еще пересохранять? Пытаюсь понять суть вопроса. Чем сам реестр не база данных? Заведите себе ключ типа `HKCU\Software\MyAppName` и там храните что нужно. Базы данных обычно делают для работы с общей базой сразу из нескольких приложений на разных машинах по сети. Вы же специализируетесь на работе с реестром, почему бы его не использовать тогда на всю катушку?

Comment: Просто такой механизм, что данные (название программ, кто их сделал, версии программ) берутся из реестра, переносятся в бд, а потом из бд они переносятся в форму (почему именно так, к сожалению потому что здесь по ТЗ обязательно наличие бд, я с этим ничего не могу сделать)

Comment: А что тогда можно почитать в таком случае, чтобы примерно понимать как работать с реестром?

Comment: Чуть позже покажу как работать с реестром, правда без БД. Для БД я советую вам подготовиться к моему ответу: 1) Приложение создать под .NET 6, а не Framework 4.x. 2) Установить NuGet пакет Entity Framework Core 6. 3) Изучить подход к формированию и миграциям БД под названием Code First. 4) Познакомиться с Linq и как он используется для работы с БД. - тогда у вас получится легко реализовать то что нужно, а я постараюсь показать всё про реестр в той форме, в которой вам будет удобно прикрутить к этому всем EF Core. Вас возможно удивит, то при таком подходе не придется писать SQL запросы вручную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте современный дотнет для разработки - .NET 6, создайте новый тестовый проект.

Написал короткий пример.

Обратите внимание, ваше приложение должно быть строго собрано как `x64`, а не `Any CPU`, в противном случае при обращении к реестру надо явно задавать `RegistryHive`.

Для начала, создам модель данных.

```
public class RegistryUninstallInfo
{
    [DisplayName("Наименование")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        
    [DisplayName("Версия")]
    public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Разработчик")]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string UninstallString { get; set; }
}
```

Для нагладности дизайнер формы я не использовал, поэтому построил форму прямо в конструкторе. Просто вставьте код в проект.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WinFormsAppRegistry;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<RegistryUninstallInfo> Applications { get; } = new BindingList<RegistryUninstallInfo>();
    private RegistryUninstallInfo SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = "Пример работы с реестром для StackOverflow на русском";
        MinimumSize = new Size(600, 400);
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        var panel = new TableLayoutPanel() { RowCount = 2 };
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle() {  SizeType = SizeType.Percent, Height = 100 });
        panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        var table = new DataGridView() 
        { 
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
            AutoGenerateColumns = true, 
            AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill,
            ReadOnly = true,
            AllowUserToAddRows = false,
            SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        };
        table.DataSource = Applications;
        table.CellDoubleClick += Table_CellDoubleClick;
        table.SelectionChanged += Table_SelectionChanged;
        SetDoubleBuffered(table, true);
        panel.Controls.Add(table, 0, 0);
        var button = new Button() { Text = "Обновить" };
        button.Click += UpdatedButton_Click;
        panel.Controls.Add(button, 0, 1);
        Controls.Add(panel);          
    }

    public static void SetDoubleBuffered(Control c, bool value)
    {
        typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.SetValue(c, value);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadRegistry();
    }
    private void UpdatedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadRegistry();
    }

    private void Table_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView table = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (table.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            SelectedItem = table.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as RegistryUninstallInfo;
    }

    private void Table_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(JsonSerializer.Serialize(SelectedItem, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping }));
    }

    private void LoadRegistry()
    {
        Applications.Clear();
        using var section = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (string keyName in section.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using var key = section.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            string name = key.GetValue("DisplayName")?.ToString();
            if (name != null)
            {
                Applications.Add(new RegistryUninstallInfo
                {
                    DisplayName = name,
                    DisplayVersion = key.GetValue("DisplayVersion")?.ToString(),
                    Publisher = key.GetValue("Publisher")?.ToString(),
                    UninstallString = key.GetValue("UninstallString")?.ToString(),
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Костыль `SetDoubleBuffered` делает так чтобы таблица не притормаживала при отрисовке.

Выглядит это так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать на строчку двойным кликом, появится сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных как прокси здесь не очень подходит. Но у вас наверняка есть какие-то дополнительные функции в проекте, например вижу "Белый список", вот для них и используйте БД. Полностью дублировать данные в БД, которые лежат в реестре - смысла 0, потому что при обновлении данных вам придется стирать таблицу в БД полностью и записывать туда все заново, так с базами данных не делают.

Чуть подробнее я рассматривал привязки данных здесь

- [Привязка данных в DataGridView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1199457/373567)

Comment: Cпасибо большое за помощь, осталось только разобраться как реализовать тогда белый и черный списки, как я понимаю лучше сделать отдельные таблицы для программ, которые вошли в белый или черный список и таблицы для тех, которые не вошли, или ка вы думаете?

Comment: @АндрейПавлов видели строчки типа `{FF3FA798-77E6-4622-A230-668E749C08BC}` - это называтеся GUID, в .NET даже тип такой есть Guid, правда в секции Uninstall не у всех приложений он есть, но его можно найти Classes Root реестра, если чуть поглубже разобраться. Так вот, его и надо по-хорошему использовать как уникальный идентификатор приложения, на основе них и стоит строить всякие списки. Например я удалил приложение, потом поставил заново, а GUID будет тот же, то есть вы сможете идентифицировать любое приложение даже после переустановки операционной системы полностью - стильно и надежно.

Comment: Хорошо, я буду думать над реализацией этого дела, если что попрошу еще совета

Comment: @АндрейПавлов еще обратите внимание, ваше приложение должно быть строго x64, а не Any CPU, в противном случае при обращении к реестру надо явно задавать `RegistryHive`

Comment: Я понял, учту это

Comment: @АндрейПавлов про GUID нагуглил http://pyatilistnik.org/kak-uznat-iz-reestra-guid-prilozheniya-v-windows/

Comment: Спасибо еще раз вам за помощь

Comment: aepot, вы говорили про использование реестра как базы данных, я сделал отдельный вопрос на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1414771/430652