# Как из реестра сделать своеобразную базу данных?

Tags: c#, реестр

Я выполняю курсовую работу, мне там надо сделать систему для учета и контроля установленных программ, и там надо реализовать белый и черный списки, и я хотел бы узнать, а можно ли реализовать эти списки с помощью реестра

Я вижу это следующим образом: открываю настройки белого списка, наверное в реестре должна быть отдельная ветка для этого, далее идет проверка этой ветки, и если она пустая, то загружается полный список программ из реестра, потом пользователь добавляет программы в белый список, нажимает "Сохранить" и программ, которые вошли в белый список переносятся в ветку для хранения программ из белого списка, а остальные - в другую ветку, чтобы отслеживать, какие программы в белый список вошли, а какие нет, с черным списком тоже самое, но теперь как это реализовать, используя С#?

Comment: Ну, у вас есть список разделов в реестре для каждого приложения, вам никто не запрещает прямо туда добавить своих ключей. Правда для HKLM раздела права админа понадобятся. Но смысл приложения не понял, какая именно от него польза?

Comment: Практической никакой, это курсовая, чтобы показать, что я умею делать программно-аппаратные средства обеспечения информационной безопасности и что я понимаю, как там все работает

Comment: Но вопросов по реализации этих списков у меня достаточно много, и преподаватель сам настоял на том, чтобы сделать их через реестр, а не через бд

Comment: Ну вот как описали, так и делайте. / Реестр - это и есть база данных.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь касаемо реализации: вот загружается форма для настройки белого списка, и при загрузке там же надо как-то новый раздел создавать и проверять его, пустой он или нет, вот как в коде С# это выглядеть будет?

Comment: Но вы же читать ключи умеете? Писать это точно так же просто как читать.

Comment: Ок, хорошо, этот момент мне понятен, при загрузке формы смотрится раздел с программами из списка, если он пустой то грузится весь список, если не пустой то грузится все что есть