# Как исправить ошибку «Строки нельзя программным способом добавить в коллекцию строк DataGridView, если элемент управления привязан к данным.»?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть форма, на ней два DataGridView: первый берет данные из реестра и заполняется при загрузке формы, второй пустой и в него мы переносим строки из первого. При переносе с первого во второй все работает как нужно, а при переносе из второго в первый вылазит ошибка

> Строки нельзя программным способом добавить в коллекцию строк DataGridView, если элемент управления привязан к данным.

Как ее исправить?
Вот сама форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка "Добавить в список" работает как надо, а вот "Удалить из списка" нет, вот ее код:

```
private void minus_program_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Yes_white.SelectedRows)
        {
            object[] items = new object[row.Cells.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                items[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            Not_white.Rows.Add(items);
            Yes_white.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка вылазит вот на этой строчке:

```
Not_white.Rows.Add(items);
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Добавляйте данные в DataTable или что там у вас привязано к гриду.

Comment: Ну у меня они в DataSource передаются, или лучше в DataTable?

Comment: Вы не можете напрямую работать с ячейками, когда используете DataSource, вам же обэтом и пишут в ошибке, редактируйте данные там, где они у вас изначально. И что это за имена `Yes_white`, как понять, что это? Называйте члены так, чтобы не пришлось угадывать, о чем вы думали, когда придумали это имя.

Comment: Но мне не надо их редактировать, я данные беру из реестра, я просто хочу их перенести с одной таблицы в другую, и ничего более

Comment: Yes_white это набор программ, которые находятся в белом списке, Not_white - те что не вошли в него

Comment: Вы в DataSource что присваиваете - то и редактируйте. Код вы не показали, гадаю на стеклянном шаре.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412607/373567 я же вам давал уже как это делать, а вы все равно упорно пытаетесь насиловать ячейки таблицы. Зачем?

Comment: @aepot, так вы же сами говорили использовать для этого реестр, вот я и пробовал реализовать таким способом составление списка и закинуть его в отдельную ветку в реестре, и я вот столкнулся с проблемой

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Суть понятна, сейчас пробую сделать, но возникла проблема с переносом элемента из одного списка в другой, говорит что пространство имен не найдено, но про этом оно записано, а остальное все сделал

Comment: Он выделяет 'FirstOrDefault()?' и говорит, что возможно нет ссылки на сборку, но в вариантах решения сам visual studio предлагает только инвертировать оператор if

Comment: `using System.Linq;` в самом верху добавьте

Comment: Было написано, ошибка никуда не делась к сожалению

Comment: Жаль рисунки сюда вставить нельзя

Comment: @АндрейПавлов я понял свою ошибку, исправил

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: К сожалению нет, вот у меня вот такой вопрос, можно вкратце объяснить что делает вот этот кусок: 'Cast<DataGridRow>().FirstOrDefault()?.DataBoundItem is ВашТипДанных item'?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136810/discussion-between---and-aepot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схематично покажу

Берете 2 листа

```
private readonly BindingList<ВашТипДанных> list1 = new BindingList<ВашТипДанных>();
private readonly BindingList<ВашТипДанных> list2 = new BindingList<ВашТипДанных>();
```

Закидываете в `DataSource`, можно даже в конструкторе формы однократно это сделать.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = list1;
dataGridView2.DataSource = list2;
```

Затем заполняете их как нужно в методе загрузки данных.

Чтобы перекинуть выделенный элемент из списка 1 в список 2, достаточно сделать

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault()?.DataBoundItem is ВашТипДанных item)
{
    list1.Remove(item);
    list2.Add(item);
}
```

Всё, больше ничего не надо. Обратная операция выглядит точно так же.

Comment: Я сделал программу, единственное только что, вот когда вы мне показывали код, я не совсем понял что делает там InitRegistryList, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейПавлов попробуйте прочитать код. Он просто создает разделы в реестре, если их нет. Возможно оно и не надо.

Comment: ну я сидел разбирался с кодом и вот и решил уточнить, просто у нас эти разделы же уже создаются и наполняются, так что зачем их по логике делать еще раз

Comment: @АндрейПавлов возможно вы правы

Comment: Возникла проблема, я смотрел программу, и не знаю как обработать исключение "Cannot write to the registry key", возникает в 'private void AddToWhiteList(RegistryUninstallInfo info)', на строчке 'section.CreateSubKey(info.RegistryKeyName);'