# C# отнимание столбцов DataGridView

Tags: c#

Уже дня два ищу информацию, но так ничего и не нашёл. Помогите отнять время в последний двух столбцах.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxAGE.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        textBoxID.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        table.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("FIO", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Dolzhnost", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Приход", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Уход", typeof(string));



        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(kalendar.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), textBoxFN.Text, textBoxLN.Text, textBoxAGE.Value.ToString("t"), textBoxID.Value.ToString("t"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\db.txt");
        string[] values;


        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
            string[] row = new string[values.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = values[j].Trim();
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"G:\db.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()+"|");
            }
            writer.WriteLine("");
            writer.WriteLine("");
        }
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button3_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

[image: фото формы]

Данные из текстового файла

21.05.2022|Алексеев П. А.|Инженер|13:23:00|20:23:00

21.05.2022|Мельников Л. Б.|Сис.Админ|12:51:00|18:51:00

21.05.2022|Захарова В. М.|Уборщица|10:01:00|22:05:00

21.05.2022|Шаров C.T|Зам|8:56:00|21:25:00

21.05.2022|Жарко И.И|Директор|7:59:00|20:53:00

Comment: Что значит отнять? Удалить эти столбцы? Вычести из данных какое-то число?

Comment: `typeof(string)` в столбцах "Data", "Приход", "Уход" замените на `typeof(DateTime)`. Тогда операции со временем станут элементарными.

Comment: При этом задайте соответствующим столбцам в `DataGridView` желаемые форматы отображения: `DefaultCellStyle.Format` (и, при необходимости, `DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider`).

Comment: Ещё лучше вместо DataTable использовать типизированную коллекцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете пожалуйста подсказать, как их всё таки отнять?)

Comment: Что отнять, от чего отнять?

Comment: @aepot отнять столбец "уход" от столбца "приход", чтобы узнать сколько человек пробыл на работе

Comment: Сделать их `DateTime` и просто вычесть из одного другое используя обычный минус `-`. Кстати, `DataTable` вроде чуть ли не автоматом может по формулам колонки вычислять прям как Excel, но я не пробовал.

Comment: @aepot Я попробовал так 
dataGridView2[0, i].Value = dataGridView1[0, i].Value;
dataGridView2[1, i].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1[4, i].Value) - Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1[3, i].Value); 
но мне даёт ошибку "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Comment: Сделайте нормальную привязку данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1199457/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-datagridview/1199692#1199692 и работайте с классами, а не с ячейками в dgv

Comment: Смотрю на ваш код и хочется сказать "Зачем вы сами себе палки в колёса втыкаете?". Создать DataTable, которую привязать к DGV. Зачем? Вы Иксзибит - вставляете таблицу в таблицу? Если вы планируете дальше работать с данными, то используете привязку, ссылку на пример которой я привёл выше. То, как вставляете вы, подойдёт, если данные просто нужно показать пользователю и забить на то, что с ними там дальше будет

Comment: @Frehzy мне данные надо брать с txt и туда же их сохранять

Comment: А в чём проблема десериализовать данные, если они в json хранятся? Да и каким-либо другим способом эти данные конвертировать в классы. Обновите вопрос и добавьте данные, которые у вас хранятся в текстовом файле

Comment: @Frehzy добавил

Comment: @SaintHuman Добавил ответ. Если ответ помог, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку и стрелку вверх. Если будут вопросы, задавайте под ответом в комментариях

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, хотелось-бы отметить, что данные такого типа лучше хранить в базе данных. Нооо, раз уж у вас текстовый файл, то ладно.

Итак, рефакторинг вашего кода:

Паттерн, который использовал за основу MVVM - [MVVM информация](https://clck.ru/i3F5X).

Создам несколько классов, которые в дальнейшем нам будут помогать.[Что такое класс](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php):

1 - класс Person, в котором будет храниться информация о пользователях из вашего текстового файла.

```
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    private DateTime _createDateTime;
    private string _fullName;
    private RoleEnum _role;
    private DateTime _comingTime;
    private DateTime _goingTime;

    [DisplayName("Дата создания")]
    public DateTime CreateDateTime
    {
        get => _createDateTime;
        private set
        {
            _createDateTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CreateDateTime));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("ФИО")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get => _fullName;
        private set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Должность")]
    public RoleEnum Role
    {
        get => _role;
        private set
        {
            _role = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Role));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Время прихода")]
    public DateTime ComingTime
    {
        get => _comingTime;
        private set
        {
            _comingTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ComingTime));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Время ухода")]
    public DateTime GoingTime
    {
        get => _goingTime;
        private set
        {
            _goingTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GoingTime));
        }
    }

    public Person(DateTime createDateTime, string fullName, RoleEnum role, DateTime comingTime, DateTime goingTime)
    {
        CreateDateTime = createDateTime;
        FullName = fullName;
        Role = role;
        ComingTime = CreateDateTimeByOnlyTime(comingTime);
        GoingTime = CreateDateTimeByOnlyTime(goingTime);
    }

    private DateTime CreateDateTimeByOnlyTime(DateTime time) =>
        new(CreateDateTime.Year, CreateDateTime.Month, CreateDateTime.Day, time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second);
}
```

2 - класс PersonAnalysis, в котором будет храниться обработанная информация. Над названием стоит поработать и чуть подправить, чтобы оно корректнее отображало истинное его предназначение. Оставлю это на вас

```
public class PersonAnalysis : ObservableObject
{
    private string _fullName;
    private TimeSpan _timeAtWork;

    [DisplayName("ФИО")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get => _fullName;
        private set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Время на работе")]
    public TimeSpan TimeAtWork
    {
        get => _timeAtWork;
        private set
        {
            _timeAtWork = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TimeAtWork));
        }
    }

    public PersonAnalysis(string fullName, TimeSpan _timeAtWork)
    {
        FullName = fullName;
        TimeAtWork = _timeAtWork;
    }
}
```

Далее, создам перечисление, в котором буду хранить доступные должности [Enum](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.12.php):

```
public enum RoleEnum
{
    Инженер = 0,
    Директор = 1,
    СисАдмин = 2,
    Уборщица = 3
}
```

Да, я знаю, что должности можно храниться прямо с строке (string), но мне гораздо удобнее использовать. Этот момент является не обязательным. Его вполне можно выпилить и оставить просто тип `string`

Далее, реализую класс ObservableObject, который будет являться дочерним интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged и реализовывать его [Абстрактные классы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.8.php) [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0):

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Далее, создам ViewModel, в котором будут храниться и изменяться данные:

```
internal class Form1ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Person> _personsList;
    private BindingList<Person> _persons;
    private BindingList<PersonAnalysis> _personAnalyses;

    public BindingList<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Persons));
        }
    }

    public BindingList<PersonAnalysis> PersonAnalyses
    {
        get => _personAnalyses;
        set
        {
            _personAnalyses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PersonAnalyses));
        }
    }

    public Form1ViewModel(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        _personsList = persons;
        Persons = new BindingList<Person>();
        PersonAnalyses = new BindingList<PersonAnalysis>();
        LoadPerson();

        var comingTime = new DateTime(2022, 05, 21, 0, 0, 0);
        var goingTime = new DateTime(2022, 05, 21, 22, 5, 0);
        UpdatePersonAnalysesByDate(comingTime, goingTime);
    }

    private void LoadPerson()
    {
        foreach (var person in _personsList)
            Persons.Add(person);
    }

    private void UpdatePersonAnalysesByDate(DateTime comingTime, DateTime goingTime) //привяжите кнопку к данному методу и всё будет работать
    {
        PersonAnalyses.Clear();
        foreach (var person in _personsList)
            if (person.ComingTime.Ticks > comingTime.Ticks && person.GoingTime.Ticks < goingTime.Ticks)
                PersonAnalyses.Add(new PersonAnalysis(person.FullName, person.GoingTime.Subtract(person.ComingTime)));
    }
}
```

Далее, напишу конвертер из текстового файла в класс Person:

```
static IEnumerable<Person> ConvertToObject(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var properties = item.Split('|');
        yield return new Person(DateTime.Parse(properties[0]),
                                properties[1],
                                (RoleEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(RoleEnum), properties[2]),
                                DateTime.ParseExact(properties[3], "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                DateTime.ParseExact(properties[4], "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Честно, не знал, как правильнее это можно было-бы сделать, поэтому решил оставить так. Думал через Regex, но всё равно бы всё сводилось к подобной конструкции. Не карайте касаемо этого метода. По-хорошему, данные в IEnumerable должны попадать из базы данных, или на крайняк из сериализованного json файла.

Далее, создадим привязки на самой форме [Ещё один пример привязок к dgv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1199457/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-datagridview/1199692#1199692):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Form1(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new Form1ViewModel(persons);
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(DataGridView.DataSource), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Persons));
        dataGridView2.DataBindings.Add(nameof(DataGridView.DataSource), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.PersonAnalyses));
    }
}
```

Итак, логика программы следующая:

Данные (из _viewModel) привязываются к свойству [Свойства](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php) DataSource у DataGridView (далее, dgv). Таким образом, DGV лишь отображает данные, которые хранятся в указанном свойстве. Сами же данные мы изменяем из Form1ViewModel.

P.S. Я не реализовывал абсолютно всё, что есть у вас на форме. Вам нужно добавить кнопку и добавить некоторую логику обработки dateTimePicker для метода `UpdatePersonAnalysesByDate`. Под капотом он сам всё сделает. Вам нужно лишь дать ему нужные данные. Я для этого создал 2 переменные.

P.S.S. Изначально создавал консольное приложение, но потом решил сделать полностью, но пересоздавать проект было лень, поэтому в Program существует некоторый костыль :)

Ссылка на проект: https://dropmefiles.com/aed3B . Будет доступен только 14 дней. Если знаете файлообменики получше, укажите, пожалуйста, ссылку

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: `RoleEnum` - неоправданно. Должности в конторе могут появляться новые с течением времени. Что тогда, перекомпилировать приложение? / Проект можно хранить на GitHub или Bitbucket.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Касаемо RoleEnum я уже в ответе написал. Тем не менее, как я уже сказал выше, в идеале хранить эти данные в базе данных. Как вариант, можно всё-таки хранить данные в виде строки, но создать публичный метод в классе Person TryGetRoleEnum, который бы пытался вернуть Enum. Если-бы у него не получилось, то default. Если можете предложить другую идея - готов с радостью выслушать, т.к. сам полностью понимаю вашу претензию, но уйти от неё не могу уже из проекта в проект и найти альтернативу. Касаемо github - не хочу замусоривать его Я недавно только почистил от старых репозиториев

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы не приняли другой ответ, значит он вас чем-то не устраивает. Хотя он показывает правильный способ - использование типизированных коллекций. Но вам, вероятно, пока это кажется слишком сложным.

Попробую дай свой ответ, основанный на слегка переделанном вашем коде.

---

Для работы с датой/временем следует использовать тип `DateTime` вместо `string`. Тогда операции со временем станут элементарными.

При этом зададим соответствующим столбцам в `DataGridView` желаемые форматы отображения: `DefaultCellStyle.Format` (и, при необходимости, `DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider`).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridView;
    Button openButton;
    Button saveButton;
    Button calculateWorkingTimeButton;

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        Size = new Size(1000, 500);

        dataGridView = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Right, Width = 700 };
        openButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Открыть" };
        saveButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Сохранить", Top = openButton.Bottom + 20 };
        calculateWorkingTimeButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Посчитать время работы", Top = saveButton.Bottom + 20 };

        this.Load += Form1_Load;
        openButton.Click += OpenButton_Click;
        saveButton.Click += SaveButton_Click;
        calculateWorkingTimeButton.Click += CalculateWorkingTimeButton_Click;
    }

    private void CalculateWorkingTimeButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            row["WorkingTime"] = row.Field<DateTime>("Departure") - row.Field<DateTime>("Arrival");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Arrival", typeof(DateTime));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Departure", typeof(DateTime));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("WorkingTime", typeof(TimeSpan));

        dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

        dataGridView.Columns["Date"].HeaderText = "Дата";
        dataGridView.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "Имя";
        dataGridView.Columns["Position"].HeaderText = "Должность";
        dataGridView.Columns["Arrival"].HeaderText = "Приход";
        dataGridView.Columns["Departure"].HeaderText = "Уход";
        dataGridView.Columns["WorkingTime"].HeaderText = "Время работы";

        dataGridView.Columns["Arrival"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "H:mm";
        dataGridView.Columns["Departure"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "H:mm";
        dataGridView.Columns["WorkingTime"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"h\:mm";
    }

    private void OpenButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
    }

    private void SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("test.txt"))
        {
            var values = line.Split('|');
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();

            row["Date"] = DateTime.Parse(values[0]);
            row["Name"] = values[1];
            row["Position"] = values[2];
            row["Arrival"] = DateTime.Parse(values[3]);
            row["Departure"] = DateTime.Parse(values[4]);

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        using var writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt");

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            writer.Write(row.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "|");
            writer.Write(row["Name"] + "|");
            writer.Write(row["Position"] + "|");
            writer.Write(row.Field<DateTime>("Arrival").ToString("H:mm:ss") + "|");
            writer.WriteLine(row.Field<DateTime>("Departure").ToString("H:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```

Вы не сказали главного: где, в каком месте нужно отнять время и что делать с результатом.
Я сделал подсчёт по нажатию на отдельную кнопку. Результат помещаю в дополнительную колонку.