# DataGridView возвращает null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть дгв2, в котором находятся чекбоксы. По какой то причине, при попытке получить значение ячейки, я получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, хочу посмотреть в содержимое ячейки вот так

```
private void Import_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Получаю ошибку

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get вернул null.
```

Юмор в том, что есть код, который обращается к дгв2 точно так же, и никаких проблем, работает всегда.
В нем я сохраняю дгв2 в бд.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string src = "0", upd = "0";
            if (radioButton1.Checked) src = "1";
            if (checkBox1.Checked) upd = "1";

            MySql.command($"UPDATE import SET link = '{MySql.escape(textBox2.Text)}', isupdate = '{upd}', source = '{src}', type = '{MySql.escape(comboBox1.Text)}', sklad = '{MySql.escape(comboBox2.Text)}', skip = '{textBox1.Text}', group_id = '{textBox3.Text}' WHERE name = '{MySql.escape(name)}'");

            MySql.command($"DELETE FROM import_ WHERE import_name = '{MySql.escape(name)}'");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                string combobox = "----------";
                if (dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value as string != null) combobox = dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                MySql.command($"INSERT INTO import_ (columnindex, import_name, comboBox, checkBox) VALUES ('{i}','{MySql.escape(name)}','{MySql.escape(combobox)}','{dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value}')");
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Сохранено");
        }
```

Приведу еще код, который создает и заполняет все дгв.

```
private void loadGridsInfo()
        {
            var dt = MySql.getTable($"SELECT columnindex, comboBox, checkBox FROM import_ WHERE import_name = '{name}'");
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(n => int.Parse(n[0].ToString())).CopyToDataTable();
            int count = dt.Rows.Count;
            int min;
            if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count < count) min = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            else                                     min = count;

            for (int i = 0; i < min ; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() == "True") dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = true;

                dataGridView3.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            }
        }

private void adaptGrids()
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridView3.Columns.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var clmn1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                var clmn2 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

                clmn1.HeaderText = "C" + i;
                clmn2.HeaderText = "C" + i;
                clmn1.Width = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
                clmn2.Width = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width;
                clmn1.DataSource = comboBox;

                dataGridView2.Columns.Add(clmn2);
                dataGridView3.Columns.Add(clmn1);
            }
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
        }
```

Один из тех случаев, когда даже не знаю куда копать. Есть идеи?

---

Comment: Я вижу у вас несколько DGV, быть может вы выбрали не ту, которая нужна, а исключения можно избежать например вот так `dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value?.ToString() ?? "<null>"`. _который обращается к дгв2 точно так же_ - не вижу dgv2, вижу dgv3.

Comment: Кстати, почитайте [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567), это поможет упростить код, раз в несколько. Война с ячейками таблицы - не то, чем стоит заниматься.

Comment: Хм, интересная тема. Но есть некоторые вопросов. К примеру  я получаю из базы данных DataTable. Как мне его быстро отобразить в дгв, обычно я это делаю через DataSource. Как я понял, количество колонок определяется классом Person, и менять быстро мы это не можем. А так же нету возможности обращаться к ячейкам или колонкам по индексу, а не по имени.

Comment: aepot, если не затруднит, добавьте меня в Телеграмме. Буду признателен за возможность периодически задавать вам вопросы. @nnoommaadd

Comment: `Person` в том случае - модель данных. Чтобы использовать классы в качестве моделей вместо DataTable, надо учиться использовать ORM, например Entity Framework, тогда будет только объектная модель и больше ничего. А чтение и запись данных сведется к взаимодействию с моделью, и писать SQL запросы вообще не надо будет. При чем даже таблицы создавать не надо, EF сам для вас их создаст, такой подход к разработке с участием БД называется Code First. Очень популярная схема, используется практически на всех серьезных серверах.