# Из базы данных в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-core

Нет возможности приводить код и скрины, прошу понять и простить.

Раньше использовал sql команды, сейчас перехожу на entity framework.
Работаю по большей части с datagridview. Нашёл довольно удобный способ работы с ним, создаю dataTable и привязываю его к dgv, дальше всю работу произвожу с dataTable. Весьма удобно то, что sql запросы возвращают мне как раз таблицы, которые легко конвертируются в dataTable и после можно либо редактировать их, либо сразу вывести на dgv.

С использованием EF таблиц больше нету. Есть экземпляры класса, в которых есть некоторые параметры. Вопрос, как адекватно загрузить их в dataTable? Собственно, что б экземпляр был строкой, а параметры - столбцы.

UPDATE

Пробую использовать DataBindings

```
private BindingList<dgvPriceManager> _dgvPriceManager; // в коде не обращайтесь к полю _persons, вместо этого обращайтесь к свойству Persons
        public BindingList<dgvPriceManager> dgvPriceManager
        {
            get => _dgvPriceManager;
            set
            {
                _dgvPriceManager = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public PriceManager(List<string> tovars_id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(dgvPriceManager));
            comboBox1.DataSource = tovarEdit.ToList();

            var Tovar = tovarContext.tovars.Where(n => tovars_id.Contains(n.id.ToString())).ToList();
            loadDGV1(Tovar);

            ShowDialog();
        }

        private void loadDGV1(List<Tovar> tovars)
        {
            dgvPriceManager = new BindingList<dgvPriceManager>();

            dgvPriceManager.Add(new dgvPriceManager { id = tovars.First().id.ToString(), name = tovars.First().name });
        }
```

В целом все работает. Получается такой себе EF для datagridview.
Но есть непонятка. Слабо представляю, как без костылей и кучи кода передать инфу из`List<Tovar>`в dgvPriceManager. Как видно в коде, вывел ID и Name Первого товара, буду благодарен за материал, который поможет понять, как вывести все.

UPDATE 2

Пришел пока что к такому коду.

```
private void loadDGV1(List<Tovar> tovars)
        {
            dgvPriceManager = new BindingList<dgvPriceManager>();

            tovars.ForEach(d => dgvPriceManager.Add(new dgvPriceManager { id = d.id.ToString(), name = d.name, price_in = d.price_in, price_out = d.price_out, new_Price_in = d.price_in, new_Price_Out = d.price_out }));
        }
```

Цель достигнута, я вывожу информацию из DB в DGV, при этом у меня есть возможность изменять ее, как мне угодно.
Сомнение у меня вызывает разве что переборка `.ForEach()`. Не будет ли тупняков, если у меня будет, допустим, 50 000 товаров.
При привязке dgv к DataTable, приходилось брать первые 500 товаров, ибо если их больше, загрузка окна занимала до 10 секунд, что недопустимо.

Если есть советы, по улучшению этого решения, буду рад услышать.

Comment: Не надо вам больше `DataTable`, переходите на `BindingList<T>` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore версия 8.0.22
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore версия 3.1.1
@AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Добавил. Все верно, winforms

Comment: @aepot Пробую ваш вариант, обновил вопрос.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.localview-1.tobindinglist