# Извлечение данных из текстового файла в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. В универе мне дали задание - сделать прогу на с#, в которой данные из .txt отображаются в таблице в DataGridView.
При этом надо создать класс со свойствами

```
public string Client { get; set; } // имя учетной записи
public string Computer { get; set; } // имя компютера клиента
public int ProductID { get; set; } // продукт
public int Session { get; set; } // номер сессии (читаем из "_ss" не "sess")
public string Type { get; set; } // "LOGIN_EX" или "LOGOUT"
public DateTime Time { get; set; } // время события
```

В экземпляре класса будут храниться данные записи, извлекаемой из текстового файла.

Т.е мне надо сделать процедуру, которая будет выковыривать данные из файла и класть в эти свойства, далее из них я передаю в DataGridView?

За ответы заранее спасибо

Comment: ну в целом вы разбили уже все на маленькие задачи, если до сих пор трудно, разбейте каждую из вышеуказанных задач ещё на подзадачи, и вперёд) я и мы на SO в тебя верим

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!