# Организация логики проекта

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Изучаю шарп и друг подкинул идею по проекту, а именно система учета заказов багетной мастерской.

Я продумал логику(хз насколько правильная она или нет).Суть ее в том, что есть главный класс(вынесенный в отдельный файл класса) он является главным, описывает базовые функции расчетов заказов(сразу уточню, что заказы разного типа могут быть), потому что некоторые расчеты одинаковы для разных видов заказов, и я хотел дальше создать несколько форм по как раз таки категориям заказов, категории бы выбирались на форме по типу меню.  После этого я хотел унаследоваться от главного класса, где уже есть шаблонные методы расчетов и добавить в наследников другие методы которые нужны соответствующему типу заказа.

В общем есть 4 textbox'a и label. С текстбоксов передаются значения(только цифры), в класс, который венесен в файл класса. В данном классе считается периметр, далее подставляется из текстбокса цена по оформлению и все это складывается и выводится на label, динамически, по изменению текстбоксов.

Далее в коде описан хендлер, который обрабатывает ввод только цифр(событие на keyPress). Далее вызывается событие, которое передает значения текстбоксов в класс, для расчетов.

```
private void keyEnter_textbox(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
        {
            if (!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) && !((e.KeyChar == ',') &&
                    (((TextBox)sender).Text.IndexOf(",") == -1) &&
                    (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length != 0)) && e.KeyChar != 8) 
            { e.Handled = true; }
            else { summ_label_textbox(sender, e); }
        }
        private void summ_label_textbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text  = new  Order(textBox6.Text,textBox5.Text,textBox4.Text,textbox3.Text).BaguetteSumm().ToString();
        }
```

Подскажите, как же организовывать логику передачи текстбоксов и вообще проекта в целом, чтобы я смог и вызывать методы класса без проблем, и чтобы события не создавали миллион объектов при обработке.

P.S. Как организовывать это все, если к примеру класс будет абстракт и наследники будут реализовывать свои методы с использованием методов базового класса. Как в этом плане все передавать, обращаться к методам. Просто хочу сразу делать логику по нормальному, чтобы не было говнокода потом.

Comment: Слишком много вопросов. Здесь принято 1 пост = 1 вопрос. Отредактируйте, уберите лишнее, оставьте только один вопрос. Если у вас несколько вопросов, вы можете задать их отдельными постами. На все на это ответы есть, только в комплексе получится каша, так что давайте по отдельности.

Comment: Начните с того чтобы заменить все текстбоксы, куда надо вводить только числа на `NumericUpDown` ([документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown)). Текущий вопрос можно удалить, затем получше подготовиться, и задать новый уже конкретно сфокусированный на одной проблеме.

Comment: Понял, сейчас попробую разбить вопросы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что я сейчас покажу, сломает мозг, но зато потом настолько понравится, что вы не сможете без этого писать код. Это называется **Привязка данных** (Data Binding). Штука очень полезная, при чем настолько, что в WPF и других более мощных UI движках без нее в принципе невозможно ничего вменяемого написать. А в Winforms про нее знают единицы.

Как вы обычно пишете код:

- Создаете контрол
- Если в контроле что-то произошло, создаете обработчик
- В обработчике что-то считаете
- Записываете результат в другие контролы

Как пишут код с привязками данных

- Создаете контрол
- Создаете модель данных, реализующую интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChnaged`
- Привязываете контрол к свойству в модели данных, то есть сообщаете контролу, где брать данные для показа
- Меняете значение в модели данных, а контрол **обновляется сам**

Вы уже начали уносить из класса окна логику работы приложения в другие классы - отлично, значит привязки вам понравятся, так как они позволяют делать это очень легко.

К делу, вот реализация `INotifyPropertyChnaged`

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Выглядит страшновато, но пока с этим классом разбираться не надо, просто добавьте его в проект отдельным файлом.

Далее я начну писать приложение, которое будет считать периметр прямоугольника, оно содержит два контрола `TextBox`, в них я буду вводить вводные данные и один `Label`, который будет отображать результат.

Для этого, создам вот такую модель данных

```
public class Measures : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _width;
    private int _height;
    private int _perimeter;

    public int Width
    {
        get => _width; 
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            CalculatePerimeter();
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get => _height; 
        set
        {
            _height = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            CalculatePerimeter();
        }
    }

    private void CalculatePerimeter()
    {
        Perimeter = Width + Height * 2;
    }

    public int Perimeter
    {
        get => _perimeter;
        private set
        {
            _perimeter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Она наследует класс `NotifyPropertyChanged`, и из него использует метод `OnPropertyChanged()`, он как раз и нужен для того чтобы сообщать контролам, что данные изменились, и Windows Forms такой подход к разработке поддерживает нативно. То есть всю работу по обновлению контролов я отдаю самому UI движку Winforms, а сам концентрируюсь на написании полезного кода.

Чтобы всё было очевидно, контролы я создал прямо в коде конструктора. То есть дизайнер формы я вообще не трогал. А это значит, что просто создав новое Winforms приложение и скопировав код из этого ответа, вы сможете запустить и попробовать всё то что я здесь показал.

Код формы:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Measures _data;
    private TextBox widthInput;
    private TextBox heightInput;
    private Label resultLabel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown };
        widthInput = CreateTextBox();
        panel.Controls.Add(widthInput);
        heightInput = CreateTextBox();
        panel.Controls.Add(heightInput);
        resultLabel = new Label() { AutoSize = true };
        panel.Controls.Add(resultLabel);
        Controls.Add(panel);

        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private TextBox CreateTextBox()
    {
        TextBox result = new TextBox() { Margin = new Padding(5), MaxLength = 5 };
        result.TextChanged += Result_TextChanged;
        return result;
    }

    private void Result_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox tbx)
        {
            tbx.BackColor = tbx.Text.Length == 0 || int.TryParse(tbx.Text, out _) ? SystemColors.Window : Color.LightPink;
        }
    }

    private void BindControls(Measures data)
    {
        widthInput.DataBindings.Clear();
        widthInput.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), data, nameof(Measures.Width), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        heightInput.DataBindings.Clear();
        heightInput.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), data, nameof(Measures.Height), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        resultLabel.DataBindings.Clear();
        resultLabel.DataBindings.Add(nameof(Label.Text), data, nameof(Measures.Perimeter));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _data = new Measures();
        BindControls(_data);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, у меня вообще нет обработчиков событий, связанных с логикой приложения. Во время работы приложения будут функционировать только привязки данных.

**Отвечая на вопрос про логику** - вот собствено она и есть, класс для данных создается однажды и редактируется из интерфейса напрямую. При этом вы сможете создать новый класс с данными, снова вызвать `BindControls` для новой модели данных и готово. Эта модель легко сериализуется, сохраняется или читается из БД и т.д., в ней нет ничего лишнего.

Выглядит это так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`(4 + 6) * 2 = 20` всё верно.

Кстати, при вводе неверных данных никаких исключений не возникает, просто вычисления не производятся. Я добавил обработчик `Result_TextChanged` только для того чтобы показать пользователю, что ввод неверен, для этого я меняю фон текстбокса на розовый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советую так же поступить. Тем более проверки `KeyPress` не защищают от ввода неверных данных, я легко смогу вставить в текстбокс мусор из буфера обмена через <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.

Поиграйте с этим проектом, посмотрите как работает. Потом решите, подходит оно или нет.

Ранее я рассказывал, как привязывать коллекции в Winforms: [Привязка данных в DataGridView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1199457/373567)

Comment: Ох, не ожидал такого ответа. Спасибо большое, я пробежался и чуть уловил смысл, завтра уже буду разбираться и щупать что,  да как.  В принципе логику я вроде понял, так что думаю дальше будет легче) Я вообще по сути хотел с бэком работать в дальнейшем, просто тут подвернулся проект для опыта, он по сути не должен быть замороченным, но я решил что лучше сразу приучаться к тому, чтобы писать "красиво" вот и спросил про логику организации в целом)

Comment: А что за винформы у вас такие красивые? Я еще не обновлялся до .NET 7/Win 11.

Comment: @Kreag3 ни к чему не призываю, но если только учишься и думаешь, что у тебя будет большой проект/считаешь, что необходимо отделять логику от представления, то проще сразу начать с WPF, т.к: по сути на WPF легко писать приложения с паттерном MVVM (то же самое, что в ответе aepot'a, только проще); WPF намного современнее чем формы; соответственно материалов по WPF и MVVM больше, чем по формам. ИМХО, винформы нужны для неболших проектов или для того чтобы понять как в целом работать и создавать десктопные приложения, без паттернов и разделений логики и представлений

Comment: @Kalmankantaja это .NET 6/Win 11 дефолтный вид, 4к моник 200%.

Comment: @Pekor я начинал с винформ, и чтобы по-настоящему понять, как оно устроено, надо все-таки повозиться с этими несчастными контролами. Иначе если сразу сядешь на привязки в WPF, оно будет выглядеть как магия, а что там под капотом происходит - будет далеко не сразу понятно. Хотя каждому своё. :)

Comment: @Pekor Я понимаю что wpf от winforms отличается в лучшую сторону, просто winforms потому что опыта не так много и их я уже "щупал" их раньше, при этом проект уже был написан на winforms и попросили доделать несколько фич, но проект уж очень криво сделан и я решил, а почему бы не переделать, но переделать я захотел правильно, включая корректно выстроенную логику и правильное использование инструментов, отсюда и возникли вопросы

Answer (score 0):

Я зайду немного с другой стороны. Вы сейчас мыслите с точки зрения пользователя/дизайнера интерфейса, что с одной стороны неплохо, но на мой взгляд не на этапе старта/разработки проекта. Для начала возьмите ручку/карандаш и составьте список того, что у Вас есть (я не погружён в предметную область, но ниже то, что возникает в голове):

- багеты

  - варианты/оформление/цвет
  - ингридиенты (глютен, веган, кошер, халяль, диета)
  - размеры
  - кто сделал (пекарь, фея, сам купил)?
  - и т.д. и т.п.
- заказы

  - сроки поставки/доставки
  - поставщик (курьер, служба доставки, самовывоз)
  - метод оплаты
  - скидка?
  - промо?
  - отменён?
  - заказ от партнёра?
  - и т.д. и т.п.

Список может показаться избыточным, но уверяю Вас, как только Вы начнёте собирать и анализировать данные (что есть/будет, что/как обрабатывать и что сохранять/отдавать) Вы так не подумаете. Определите также взаимосвязь между данными, какие данные обязательны, а какие опциональны. После того, как Вы это сделаете будет понятно какая "логика" Вам нужна, какие формы, контроллеры, сервисы и т.д. и т.п.

Хочу лишь донести до Вас, что создание программных продуктов нужно начинать не с визуального оформления, а с проработки предметной модели, т.е. осознания того, ЧТО нужно делать, КАКИМ образом обрабатывать поступившую и имеющуюся информацию и КАК (в каком виде) её сохранять/отображать.

Вы ведь скорее всего сталкивались с программами, которые доступны на нескольких платформах (Win, nix, Android, iOS) и даже для одной платформы могут быть несколько реализаций (WinFroms, WPF, Electron, etc.). Всё это возможно потому, что при разработке происходит разделение кода на слои:

- слой сохранения/предоставления данных
- слой содержащий саму логику
- слой отображения/взаимодействия с данными

Сейчас, Вам может показаться, что всё это слишком избыточно для Вашего маленького проекта и самое главное начать, но чем дальше Вы будете погружаться в него, чем больше изменений будете в него вносить, чем больше будете добавлять/изменять/удалять какие-нибудь функции, тем больше будете к этому приходить сами.

Написал отдельным ответом, так как много для комментария, а вопрошающий напомнил мне самого себя много лет назад.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду теперь это учитывать и стараться думать правильнее)

Comment: Просто все это возникло из-за того, что я не хотел все это писать в одном файле, так как это чревато последствиями, а когда начал выносить начали возникать проблемы и вопросы, поэтому и спросил как лучше, но все равно спасибо еще раз, я теперь лучше понимаю что к чему)