# ComboBox в WinForms добавление элемента при получении данных из столбца базы данных

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Может кто-то объяснит. В ComboBox привязал данные одного стоблца, получаемые из SQL Server.
Однако мне необходимо, чтобы cmbFKTO.SelectedIndex = 0, начинался со моего значения, а не значения полученного из DB.

Уточнение, я привязал столбец в режиме привязки данных(Источник данных --> итд)

Comment: дополнения пишите в сам вопрос, а не в комменты, его можно редактировать, покажите код, относящийся к вопросу, что значит "с моего значения"?

Comment: я сам код в этом случае не писал а в форме ComboBox задачи сделал привязку ((источник данных) в моем случае tblFktoBindingSource,  отобразить члена (FKTO) итд). Таким образом первый элемет ComboBox это первый элемент в столбце базы данных, а мне нады добавить свой пунтк (все FKTO).

Comment: Ну привязали коллекцию, привяжите свойство со значением текущего элемента из этой коллекции. SelectedValue, не помню точно, вроде еще свойство ValueMember надо настроить.

Comment: не понял, в свойствах SelectedValueChanged?

Comment: События тут вообще не при чем. Я про привязки.

Comment: А где это настраивается?

Comment: `DataBindings` [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450968/373567), разберитесь как работают привязки, вы пока не разобрались.

Comment: так и не пойму, в SelectedValue предлагает только BindingSource к базе данных. но мне нужно одно поле не из базы данных

Comment: Вы почитайте пример, если мало, там еще ссылка в конце есть одна, и не поле, а свойство