# c#, datatimepicker

Tags: c#, дата, время

```
 DateTime date = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            label27.Text = date.ToString("dd/MM");
            label28.Text =
```

У меня есть datatimepicker, там я выбираю день и месяц, в label27 у меня выводится день и месяц которые я выбрал. Вопрос: как сделать что бы в label28 выводился следующий день.
Пример:
label27 = 26.03
label28 = 27.03

Comment: `date.AddDays(1)`

Comment: А можно ли как то сделать что бы в dateTimePicker можно было выбрать только понедельник? Что бы dateTimePicker не давало выбрать вторник среду и тд

Comment: `label28` - а если таких меток будет 328 - вы с ума не сойдете? Используйте коллекции, а не вот это вот всё. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1296394/373567 есть еще привязки данных: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450968/373567

Comment: Если это WinForms, то у него DateTimePicker нету (могу ошибаться) инструментов блокирования выбора дат, только `MinDate` и `MaxDate` при помощи которых можно сделать нужный диапазон. Единственное наверно, как там можно сделать, это скорей всего через `ValueChanged`, по которому вы смотрите, подходит дата или нет, и если нет, то откатываете выбор. Если это WPF, то стоит смотреть в сторону `BlackoutDates`, это некая коллекция запрещенных дат, правда она статична, и вы не сможете через нее сделать разрешить только все понедельники.

Comment: @aepot на счёт коллекций, мне кажеться, вряд-ли у автора должен быть массив леблов, скорее всего он просто не даёт им названия, а они ж автоматом называются `label1`, `label2`, `label...`