# DataGridView взять данные с таблицы C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как можно сохранить значение с ячейки в переменную?

```
namespace FirstApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        
 
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
            var column1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column1.HeaderText = "1"; //текст в шапке
            column1.Width = 30; //ширина колонки
            //column1.ReadOnly = true; //значение в этой колонке нельзя править
            column1.Name = "1"; //текстовое имя колонки, его можно использовать вместо обращений по индексу
            column1.Frozen = true; //флаг, что данная колонка всегда отображается на своем месте
            column1.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); //тип нашей колонки
 
            var column2 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column2.HeaderText = "2";
            column2.Width = 30;
            column2.Name = "2";
            column2.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column3 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column3.HeaderText = "3";
            column3.Width = 30;
            column3.Name = "3";
            column3.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column4 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column4.HeaderText = "4";
            column4.Width = 30;
            column4.Name = "4";
            column4.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column5 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column5.HeaderText = "5";
            column5.Width = 30;
            column5.Name = "5";
            column5.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column6 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column6.HeaderText = "6";
            column6.Width = 30;
            column6.Name = "6";
            column6.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column7 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column7.HeaderText = "7";
            column7.Width = 30;
            column7.Name = "7";
            column7.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column8 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column8.HeaderText = "8";
            column8.Width = 30;
            column8.Name = "8";
            column8.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column9= new DataGridViewColumn();
            column9.HeaderText = "9";
            column9.Width = 30;
            column9.Name = "9";
            column9.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column10 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column10.HeaderText = "10";
            column10.Width = 30;
            column10.Name = "10";
            column10.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column11 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column11.HeaderText = "11";
            column11.Width = 30;
            column11.Name = "11";
            column11.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column12 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column12.HeaderText = "12";
            column12.Width = 30;
            column12.Name = "12";
            column12.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column13 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column13.HeaderText = "13";
            column13.Width = 30;
            column13.Name = "13";
            column13.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column14 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column14.HeaderText = "14";
            column14.Width = 30;
            column14.Name = "14";
            column14.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
            var column15 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column15.HeaderText = "15";
            column15.Width = 30;
            column15.Name = "15";
            column15.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 
 
 
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column4);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column5);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column6);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column7);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column8);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column9);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column10);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column11);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column12);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column13);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column14);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column15);
 
 
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false; //запрешаем пользователю самому добавлять строки
 
            
                //Добавляем строку, указывая значения колонок поочереди слева направо
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x14", "x15");
 
 
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
            {
           
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();  //<-- 3 колонка с которой нужно взять и сохр значение в переменную
            
            }
 
         
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам было [дано полное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1455829/373567) с подробнейшим примером, как сделать это в WPF. Думаете после того как вы не смогли найти в готовом коде `DataTable`, то [сможете с Winforms разобраться?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567) А дальше что, консоль будет?

Comment: Начните с чтения документации https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview

Comment: object o = dataGridView1[x, y].Value;

Comment: тогда уж int x = Convert.ToInt32(o); Кстати, вы же умеете цикл `for`, почему у вас в коде одно и то же повторяется? Сделайте цикл.

Comment: @Виктор а я и не вам)

Comment: Уважаемый, если у вас возникают дополнительные вопросы в ходе решения конкретной задачи, не бросайте это, не игнорируйте комментарии, что вам пишут, спрашивайте у людей конкретно что вам надо, и так далее. А то вот вы про WPF спросили, вам сказали как, вы и слова в ответ не сказали, бросили, пошли в старый, ужасный WinForms, а почему? А потому что вы побоялись идти дальше, а зря, там все оооочень просто, было бы желание разбираться, да?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ щас скажут, что злые зазнавшиеся программисты обижают новичков :)

Comment: @aepot обидеть человека нельзя, можно только обидеться ))

Comment: @Kalmankantaja что злые зазнавшиеся программисты вынуждают новичков обижаться :)

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Мне в технаре задали сделать кодировку Хэминга и я пытался сделать в WPF, но после ответа на мой первый вопрос понял, что это будет сложно. Подумал что в winforms это будет легче сделать

Comment: Да одинаково по сложности, все равно разбираться придется. Начните с простого, сделайте логику из фиксированных значений, просто создайте и заполните массив переменных. А уже потом к нему прикручивайте интерфейс, при чем неважно какой. Приходите с конкретными вопросами, поможем, если сможем.

Comment: Вот вам WPF: `ObservableCollection<MyClass> Items {get;} public MainWindow(){ DataContext = this; }` и XAML: `<DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}" />`, все.... У вас привязка, полноценная и рабочая, где ваши новые ячейки автоматом будут в коллекции `Items`. Сложно? Да я не сказал бы... Это основа основ, которую вы проигнорировали, побоялись.

Comment: @aepot После того как получится сделать прогу, сделаю все аккуратно и красиво

Comment: Для начала сделайте хоть в консоли, логику, скелет, алгоритмы. Чтобы работало. Данные хоть из файла грузите, хоть в коде прописывайте. А потом выбирайте UI движок и начинайте интерфейс.

Comment: @aepot Снова здраствуйте)  я тут что-то пытался сделать. Вот что получилось:
     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; ++j)
                {
                    //Значения ячеек хряняться в object
                    
                 object o = dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
                  
                }
            }
Как теперь можно взаимодействовать с object o. Например засунуть одну из ячеек  в label

Comment: `label.Text = o?.ToString() ?? "нет значения";`