# Не получаю данные при выборе ключей RSA из ListBox'a

Tags: c#, winforms, rsa

На форме есть listbox, кнопка (при нажатие генерируются ключи RSA)
Задача такая, чтобы при генерации сохранялся приватный ключ, публичный ключ и имя файла оставались в свойствах класса (для дальнейшего обращения)
При выборе элемента имени файла ключа из listbox'a выводить данные выбранного ключа (от имени файла)
Класс **RSAKeys**

```
public class RSAKeys
{
        public string PublicKeyXML { get; set; }
        public string PrivateKeyXML { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
 
        public RSAKeys(string parPublicXMLKey, string partPrivateXMLKey)
        {
            PrivateKeyXML = partPrivateXMLKey;
            PublicKeyXML = parPublicXMLKey;
        }
 
        public RSAKeys() { } // Добавил пустой конструктор, потому что без него просто ругается на добавление аргументов.
 
        public override string ToString() => FileName;
}
```

Кнопка генерации ключей RSA

```
private void GenNewKEYS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button
{
    using (RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key
    {
       string publicKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true); // Открытый ключ RSA
       string PrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false); // Закрытый ключ RSA
       string fname = Path.GetFileName("PrivateKey_#1"); // Тут рандомно сохраняется путь до приватного ключа
            
       //RSAKeys key = new RSAKeys(); 
       RSAKeys key = new(publicKeyXml, fname);          
       rsaKeys.Add(key);
       File.WriteAllText(fname+".xl", PrivateKeyXML);
       listBox1.Items.Add(rsaKeys); // Добавляю в listBox отображение имени файла приватного ключа
    }
}
```

Далее

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //RSAKeys key = new();
    // string curKey = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
 
     RSAKeys curKey = (RSAKeys)listBox1.SelectedItem;
     // через curKey нужно сделать обращение с выбранным ключём чтобы он отображал все нужные данные.
}
```

Но получаю ошибки на `null` и

> System.InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.String" к типу "RSAKeys".

Comment: `SelectedValue`

Comment: @aepot, `System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.` - это в `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Понял, в чем дело. Научитесь использовать привязки, в листбоксе данные не удастся хранить полноценно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567 тогда SelectedValue заработает.

Comment: @aepot, сложно как-то, а можно проще?

Comment: Что сложного, берете `private readonly BindingList<RSAKeys> rsaKeys = new BindingList<RSAKeys>();` вместо того списка что у вас. Берете однократно при запуске приложения делаете `listBox1.DataSource = rsaKeys;`, строчку `listBox1.Items.Add(rsaKeys);` удаляете, и готово.

Comment: Ааааа, тю блин, не знал, спасибо! Буду пользоваться )

Comment: У вас кстати в классе `RSAKeys` бардак, присваиваете в конструкторе одно, отображаете в ToString другое.

Comment: Вам вообще не нужен `ToString`, вместо этого задайте однократно `listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";`. Не ленитесь читать документацию, там много всего интересного https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox

Comment: @aepot, спасибо большое! Всё получилось!! А подскажите, как мне можно при загрузке формы, загрузить данные из файлов в класс свойств RSAKeys и добавить имена ключей в listBox те, которые есть. Ключи хранятся в папке рядом с файлом

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Попробуйте сами, а если не получится, задайте отдельный вопрос.