# Из текущей папки с ключами загрузить их данные при загрузке формы

Tags: c#, winforms, rsa

.Net .4.7
[Ранняя тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461599/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-rsa-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listboxa?noredirect=1#comment2614250_1461599)

Подскажите, если при нажатие кнопки у меня генерируются ключи, я добавляю их в класс `RSAKeys` и сохраняю локально приватный и публичный ключи RSA в папку то после открытие формы заново подгрузить данные свойства ключей (Если папку с к ключами уже есть) ? Чтобы повторно не создавать.

Класс свойства ключей:

```
public class RSAKeys
{
        public string PublicKeyXML { get; set; }
        public string PrivateKeyXML { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
 
        public RSAKeys(string parPublicXMLKey, string partPrivateXMLKey)
        {
            PrivateKeyXML = partPrivateXMLKey;
            PublicKeyXML = parPublicXMLKey;
        }
 
        public RSAKeys() { } // Добавил пустой конструктор, потому что без него просто ругается на добавление аргументов.
 
        public override string ToString() => FileName;
}
```

Класс для управления ключами:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    BindingList<RSAKeys> rsaKeys;
 
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      rsaKeys= new BindingList<RSAKeys>();
 
      listBox1.DataSource = rsaKeys;
      listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
    }
 
    private void GenNewKEYS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button
    {
      int i = 0;
      using (RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key
       {
          i++;
          string publicKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true); // Открытый ключ RSA
          string PrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false); // Закрытый ключ RSA
          string fname = Path.GetFileName($"PrivateKey_#_{i}"); // Тут рандомно сохраняется
        
          RSAKeys key = new RSAKeys();
          key.PublicKeyXML = publicKeyXML;
          key.PrivateKeyXML = PrivateKeyXML;
          key.FileName = fname;
          
          rsaKeys.Add(key);
          File.WriteAllText(fname+".priv", PrivateKeyXML);
          File.WriteAllText(fname+".pub", publicKeyXML);
       }
    }
 
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       RSAKeys curKey = (RSAKeys)listBox1.SelectedItem;
       // curKey.PrivateKeyXML = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(curKey.FileName+".xl").First();
       // далее что-то делаем с ключами
       
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так например

```
private void LoadKeys()
{
    string rootPath = ".";
    foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, "*.priv"))
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        RSAKeys key = new RSAKeys();
        key.PublicKeyXML = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path.GetDirectoryName(path), $"{fname}.pub"));
        key.PrivateKeyXML = File.ReadAllText(path);
        key.FileName = fname;

        rsaKeys.Add(key);
    }
}
```

Кстати, если у на диске лежит приватный XML ключ, то в нем же и публичный лежит, сравните содержимое XML файлов, обнаружите что и там и там есть публичный ключ `<Modulus>`. Отсюда вывод, а зачем, собственно, для публичного ключа используете отдельный файл на диске, если одного хватит? Непонятно.

Расширение файла не надо выдумывать, используйте `.xml`, это же XML файлы, верно? Расширение обычно дается по формату данных в файле, а не по его назначению, для назначения есть имя, то что до расширения в имени файла.

Другими словами, храните в XML если приватный ключ сохраняете, то только один файл. Чтобы убрать из него публичный ключ, достаточно загрузить файл в `RSACryptoServiceProvider` и пересохранить как публичный `rsa.ToXmlString(true)`.

Comment: Хмм, прикольно) Можно считать всё из одного файла, а я что-то пропустил как-то этот вариант ( 
То есть по сути мне просто нужно прочитать через File.ReadAllLines найти нужную строку до куда читать и всё получается.

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch я не об этом писал, а о том, что публичный ключ присутствует в файле с приватным, то есть экземпляр шифровальщика можно проинициализировать полностью и при желании извлечь из него только публичный ключ для передачи. Хранить все ключи в одном файле конечно можно, но смысл?

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch а что не так с решением, почему не принимаете?

Comment: не переживайте) Галочку ставлю когда есть возможность. Просто занят был. А так спасибо что помогаете!