# System.InvalidCastException: Заданное приведение является недопустимым

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужна помощь. Есть база данных в microsoft sql server. Я хочу чтоб таблица отобразилась на windows форме с помощью datagridview. Но при запуске появляется ошибка (в заголовке).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void CreateColumns()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("adr_id", "id");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name", "Iм'я");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("bday", "День народження");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("address", "Адреса");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("tel", "Телефон");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("IsNew", String.Empty);
    }

    private void ReadSingleRow(DataGridView dgw, IDataRecord record)
    {
        dgw.Rows.Add(record.GetInt32(0), record.GetString(1), record.GetDateTime(2), record.GetString(3), record.GetInt32(4), RowState.ModifiedNew);
    }

    private void RefreshDataGrid(DataGridView dgw)
    {
        dgw.Rows.Clear();
        string queryString = $"select * from addressee";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, dataBase.GetConnection());
        dataBase.openConnection();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ReadSingleRow(dgw, reader);
        }
        reader.Close();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label_bday_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateColumns();
        RefreshDataGrid(dataGridView1);
    }
}
```

[image: debug]

[image: debug]

[image: debug]

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. Непонятно что содержит record[2] (быть может там вообще `null`?), запрос ее заполняющий вы не показали. Кстати, как вам [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567)?

Comment: Если подебажить - что в этот момент в record?

Comment: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). Для `date` годится `GetDateTime`. Проблема не в этом.

Comment: @aepot Добавил больше информации к вопросу. По поводу record[2] вы имеете в виду какая информация в ячейке sql server? Там дата.

Answer (score 0):

record(4) заменил на GetString и заработало