# Поиск значения из ячейки DataGrid3 в Datagrid2 и если они равны то ещё один поиск из Datagrid2 в Datagrid1 если они тоже равны то +1 в Datagrid1

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть 4 DataGrid, Первый датагрид имеет таблицу с размерами товаров и сколько штук есть на данный момент этот размер товара (Номеклатура, Артикул + 9 стольбцов от XS ДО 5XL).[image: Datagrid1] Второй датагрид имеет тоже самое что и 1 только вместо количество написанны штрихкод этого продукта (Наприме 2000001312).[image: DataGrid2] Третий датагрид имеет один стольбец Штрихкод ( сюда по задумки должны вводиться точно такие же штрихкоды как из Второй датагрид).[image: DataGrid3] А Четвертый датагрид имеет тоже самое что и перый только там будет считаться количество добавленных товаров (Отчет о добавленной продукции).[image: DataGrid4]

Нужно сделать поиск значения из ячейки ( Не из текстбокса, а из ячейки в которую можно ввести любое число) DataGrid3 в DataGrid2 и если они равны то ещё один поиск из DataGrid2 в DataGrid1 (только первую ячейку) если они тоже равны то +1 в DatagGrid1 ( в ту же ячейку из DataGrid2 просто прибавить +1) и заодно добавить в DataGrid4 количество +1 (если один раз был добавлен то пишеться в ячейку 1).

Есть какие нибудь идеии что можно сделать?

```
private void dataGridViewPRIXOD_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = dataGridViewPRIXOD.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
            try
            { 
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewSTIXKOD.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(s))
                    { 
                        row.Selected = true;
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridViewOBSHIY.Rows)
                        {
                            string a = dataGridViewSTIXKOD.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                            if (row1.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(a))
                            {
                                row1.Selected = true;

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка. "+"Такой штрихкода нету в базе данных.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Чтобы понять этот вопрос, нужно сильное воображение и хорошая память, прямо как у вас. Но вы можете улучшить ситуацию и подкрепить свои объяснялки кодом и скриншотами, или схемами с примерами логики. Но для начала начните решать задачу самостоятельно, нужно понять, что именно не получается.

Comment: Я начал но у меня проблема в том что я не знаю как использовать string s = textbox.text, а именно как можно заменить этот textbox на значение указанную в ячейке

Comment: Это WPF? Или что? К чему привязаны таблицы? DataGrid или DataGridView?

Comment: DataGridView, Я  не правильно описал простите

Comment: метку winforms добавьте тогда

Comment: Я уже почти мессяц ломаю головоу как можно это реализовать. Если поможете то я вам буду сильно благодарен.

Comment: Начните с этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567