# Как можно сделать чтобы при изменение ячейки в DataGridView1 происходило автоматический поиск этого значение в DataGridView2

Tags: c#, winforms

Я имею 2 DataGridaView. В первом имееться один столбец куда вводиться значение и она польностью пустая. Второй имеет 10 солбцов с разными значениями.Как можно сделать так, чтобы при изменение ячейки в DataGridView1 происходило автоматический поиск этого значение в DataGridView2 и если оно ровно то продожение кода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск значения из ячейки DataGrid3 в Datagrid2 и если они равны то ещё один поиск из Datagrid2 в Datagrid1 если они тоже равны то +1 в Datagrid1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466469/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-datagrid3-%d0%b2-datagrid2-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%89%d1%91-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81)

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Я вам уже рассказывал в прошлом таем же вопросе, что для отслеживания изменений в данных наужна привязка данных, а воз и ныне там.